# How to rethrow InnerException without losing stack trace in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am calling, through reflection, a method which may cause an exception. How can I pass the exception to my caller without the wrapper reflection puts around it?
I am rethrowing the InnerException, but this destroys the stack trace.
Example code:

```
public void test1()
{
    // Throw an exception for testing purposes
    throw new ArgumentException("test1");
}

void test2()
{
    try
    {
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(Program).GetMethod("test1");
        mi.Invoke(this, null);
    }
    catch (TargetInvocationException tiex)
    {
        // Throw the new exception
        throw tiex.InnerException;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is another way to do this that doesn't require any voodoo. Take a look at the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668334/preserving-exceptions-from-dynamically-invoked-methods

Comment: The exception thrown in the dynamically called method is the inner exception of the "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" exception. It has its own stack trace. There really is not much else there to worry about.

Comment: use mi.Invoke(this, BindingFlags.DoNotWrapExceptions, null, null, null)

Answer (score 586, accepted):

In **.NET 4.5** there is now the [`ExceptionDispatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo) class.

This lets you capture an exception and re-throw it without changing the stack-trace:

```
using ExceptionDispatchInfo = 
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo;

try
{
    task.Wait();
}
catch(AggregateException ex)
{
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
}
```

This works on any exception, not just `AggregateException`.

It was introduced due to the `await` C# language feature, which unwraps the inner exceptions from `AggregateException` instances in order to make the asynchronous language features more like the synchronous language features.

Comment: Good candidate for an Exception.Rethrow() extension method?

Comment: Note that the ExceptionDispatchInfo class is in the System.Runtime.ExceptionServices namespace, and is not available prior to .NET 4.5.

Comment: You may need to put a regular `throw;` after the .Throw() line, because the compiler won't know that .Throw() always throws an exception. `throw;` will never be called as a result, but at least the compiler won't complain if your method requires a return object or is an async function.

Comment: Is there an implementation for .Net 4.0?

Comment: Why is a simple `throw;` not enough? I just tested it in a small console app and found the stack trace was not changed between rethrowing and not handling the exception at all.

Comment: @Taudris This question is specifically about rethrowing the inner exception, which cannot be specially handled by `throw;`. If you use `throw ex.InnerException;` the stack-trace is re-initialized at the point it is re-thrown.

Comment: Oops, missed that `InnerException` detail. Never mind, makes sense! This could be quite useful.

Comment: sometimes `InnerException` is null. What in that case?

Comment: @amitjha in case `InnerException` is null, the outer exception should just be thrown.

Comment: @amitjha `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException ?? ex).Throw();`

Comment: `throw;` **is the same** that `System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex).Throw();` and ***preserves the stacktrace*** ?

Comment: `public static T Rethrow<T>(this System.Exception ex){   ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException ?? ex).Throw();throw new System.Exception(); // noop}`

This allows to return to make compile happy. Not sure if its a great idea though..

Comment: @RedRidingHood, Nice but no need for Generic, right?  Just void.

Answer (score 88):

It **is** possible to preserve the stack trace before rethrowing without reflection:

```
static void PreserveStackTrace (Exception e)
{
    var ctx = new StreamingContext  (StreamingContextStates.CrossAppDomain) ;
    var mgr = new ObjectManager     (null, ctx) ;
    var si  = new SerializationInfo (e.GetType (), new FormatterConverter ()) ;

    e.GetObjectData    (si, ctx)  ;
    mgr.RegisterObject (e, 1, si) ; // prepare for SetObjectData
    mgr.DoFixups       ()         ; // ObjectManager calls SetObjectData

    // voila, e is unmodified save for _remoteStackTraceString
}
```

This wastes a lot of cycles compared to calling `InternalPreserveStackTrace` via cached delegate, but has the advantage of relying only on public functionality. Here are a couple of common usage patterns for stack-trace preserving functions:

```
// usage (A): cross-thread invoke, messaging, custom task schedulers etc.
catch (Exception e)
{
    PreserveStackTrace (e) ;

    // store exception to be re-thrown later,
    // possibly in a different thread
    operationResult.Exception = e ;
}

// usage (B): after calling MethodInfo.Invoke() and the like
catch (TargetInvocationException tiex)
{
    PreserveStackTrace (tiex.InnerException) ;

    // unwrap TargetInvocationException, so that typed catch clauses 
    // in library/3rd-party code can work correctly;
    // new stack trace is appended to existing one
    throw tiex.InnerException ;
}
```

Comment: Looks cool, what needs to happen after running these functions?

Comment: @vdboor: I don't quite understand your question. Did the edit clarify things?

Comment: Actually, it's not much slower than invoking `InternalPreserveStackTrace` (about 6% slower with 10000 iterations). Accessing the fields directly by reflection is about 2.5% faster than invoking `InternalPreserveStackTrace`

Comment: @Thomas: when using `InternalPreserveStackTrace`, it is much faster to create a delegate for it instead of calling with reflection every time. I compared to the former scenario.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the great code and explanations. Is it possible to add a string to the exception message so I will be able to capture not just the stack trace from where it was thrown but also the reason?

Comment: I would recommend using the `e.Data` dictionary with a string or a unique object key (`static readonly object myExceptionDataKey = new object ()`, but don't do this if you have to serialize exceptions anywhere). Avoid modifying `e.Message`, because you might have code somewhere which parses `e.Message`. Parsing `e.Message` is evil, but there may be no other choice, e.g. if you have to use a 3rd-party library with poor exception practices.

Comment: DoFixups breaks for custom exceptions if they do not have the serialization ctor

Comment: The suggested solution doesn't work if the exception doesn't have a serialization constructor. I suggest to use the solution proposed at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4557183/209727 that work well in any case. For .NET 4.5 consider to use ExceptionDispatchInfo class.

Comment: So it is. I mention in my answer that the advantage of the serialization approach lies in relying only on public APIs. Apparently some code review standards frown on using reflection to access CLR internals. As for the `ExceptionDispatchInfo` class, it's nice but not serializable (probably because it preserves Watson information in addition to the stack trace), which limits its usefulness somewhat.

Comment: The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9989557/206730 ***not require*** the exception type to be ***serializable*** ?

Answer (score 38):

I think your best bet would be to just put this in your catch block:

```
throw;
```

And then extract the innerexception later.

Comment: Or remove the try/catch altogether.

Comment: @Earwicker. Removing the try/catch is not a good solution in general as it ignores cases where cleanup code is required prior to propagating the exception up the call stack.

Comment: @Jordan - Clean up code should be in a finally block not a catch block

Comment: @Paolo - If it is supposed to be executed in every case, yes. If it is supposed to be executed only in failure case, no.

Comment: Keep in mind that InternalPreserveStackTrace isnt thread safe, so if you have 2 threads in on of these exception states... may god have mercy on us all.

Comment: This works if you "throw" immediately in the catch block, but it doesn't work if you need to "throw" outside a catch block.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker there are cases where you want to execute code in the catch, and then rethrow. Another case is when you want to rethrow a particular type of exception but catch locally anything else.

Answer (score 33):

Nobody has explained the difference between `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture( ex ).Throw()` and a plain `throw`, so here it is.

The complete way to rethrow a caught exception is to use `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture( ex ).Throw()` (only available from .Net 4.5).

Below there are the cases necessary to test this:

1.

```
void CallingMethod()
{
    //try
    {
        throw new Exception( "TEST" );
    }
    //catch
    {
    //    throw;
    }
}
```

2.

```
void CallingMethod()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception( "TEST" );
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture( ex ).Throw();
        throw; // So the compiler doesn't complain about methods which don't either return or throw.
    }
}
```

3.

```
void CallingMethod()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception( "TEST" );
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

4.

```
void CallingMethod()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception( "TEST" );
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        throw new Exception( "RETHROW", ex );
    }
}
```

Case 1 and case 2 will give you a stack trace where the source code line number for the `CallingMethod` method is the line number of the `throw new Exception( "TEST" )` line.

However, case 3 will give you a stack trace where the source code line number for the `CallingMethod` method is the line number of the `throw` call. This means that if the `throw new Exception( "TEST" )` line is surrounded by other operations, you have no idea at which line number the exception was actually thrown.

Case 4 is similar with case 2 because the line number of the original exception is preserved, but is not a real rethrow because it changes the type of the original exception.

Comment: I always thought that 'throw' didn't reset the stacktrace (as opposed to 'throw e').

Comment: @JesperMatthiesen I might be mistaken, but I heard that it depends if the exception was thrown and caught in the same file. If it's the same file, the stack trace will be lost, if it's another file, it will be preserved.

Comment: What I can find on `ExceptionDispatchInfo` points to its use when you want to re-throw outside the context of the catch, or to unwrap an `AggregateException`.

The difference I see in my tests is that `throw;` fails to capture any lines from the `try` in the stacktrace. Changing example 3 to `try { DoThrow(); } catch (Exception) { throw; }`, you'll see that the throwing line in `DoThrow` *is* included in the stacktrace, but still not the calling line from the `try`. Whereas `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture` includes that line.

Still seems like too much work outside of the primary use-cases.

Comment: The behavior from example 3 was logged as a bug against .NET Core, and fixed in .NET Core 2.1: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/9518

Answer (score 15):

```
public static class ExceptionHelper
{
    private static Action<Exception> _preserveInternalException;

    static ExceptionHelper()
    {
        MethodInfo preserveStackTrace = typeof( Exception ).GetMethod( "InternalPreserveStackTrace", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic );
        _preserveInternalException = (Action<Exception>)Delegate.CreateDelegate( typeof( Action<Exception> ), preserveStackTrace );            
    }

    public static void PreserveStackTrace( this Exception ex )
    {
        _preserveInternalException( ex );
    }
}
```

Call the extension method on your exception before you throw it, it will preserve the original stack trace.

Comment: Be aware that in .Net 4.0, InternalPreserveStackTrace is now a no-op - look in Reflector and you'll see the method is completely empty!

Comment: Scratch that: I was looking at the RC: in the beta, they've put the implementation back again!

Comment: suggestion: change PreserveStackTrace to return ex - then to throw an exception you can just say: throw ex.PreserveStackTrace();

Comment: Why use `Action<Exception>` ? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4821722/206730) use **static method**

Answer (score 12):

Based on Paul Turners answer I made an extension method

```
    public static Exception Capture(this Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex).Throw();
        return ex;
    }
```

the `return ex` ist never reached but the advantage is that I can use `throw ex.Capture()` as a one liner so the compiler won't raise an `not all code paths return a value` error.

```
    public static object InvokeEx(this MethodInfo method, object obj, object[] parameters)
    {
        {
            return method.Invoke(obj, parameters);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex) when (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException.Capture();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

Even more reflection...

```
catch (TargetInvocationException tiex)
{
    // Get the _remoteStackTraceString of the Exception class
    FieldInfo remoteStackTraceString = typeof(Exception)
        .GetField("_remoteStackTraceString",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); // MS.Net

    if (remoteStackTraceString == null)
        remoteStackTraceString = typeof(Exception)
        .GetField("remote_stack_trace",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); // Mono

    // Set the InnerException._remoteStackTraceString
    // to the current InnerException.StackTrace
    remoteStackTraceString.SetValue(tiex.InnerException,
        tiex.InnerException.StackTrace + Environment.NewLine);

    // Throw the new exception
    throw tiex.InnerException;
}
```

Keep in mind that this may break at any time, as private fields are not part of API. See further discussion on [Mono bugzilla](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=425512).

Comment: This is a really, really bad idea, as it depends on internal undocumented details about framework classes.

Comment: Turns out it's possible to preserve the stack trace without Reflection, see below.

Comment: Calling the internal `InternalPreserveStackTrace` method would be better, since it does the same thing and is less likely to change in the future...

Comment: Actually, it would be worse, as InternalPreserveStackTrace does not exist on Mono.

Comment: @daniel - well its a really, really, really bad idea for throw; to reset the stacktrace when every .net developer is trained to believe it won't. its also a really, really, really bad thing if you can't find out the source of a NullReferenceException and lose a customer/order because you can't find it. for me that trumps 'undocumented details' and definitely mono.

Comment: @Simon: `throw;` doesn't reset the stack trace. `throw e;` does.

Comment: Yeah, this is bad.  Yeah, it's a hack.  Yeah, it might break.  But write a unit test for it, and if it breaks in some future update to .NET you will find it before you release to customers, and all you'll be out is time in the future working up a new hack.

Answer (score 11):

First: don't lose the TargetInvocationException - it's valuable information when you will want to debug things.
Second: Wrap the TIE as InnerException in your own exception type and put an OriginalException property that links to what you need (and keep the entire callstack intact).
Third: Let the TIE bubble out of your method.

Answer (score 6):

Guys, you are cool.. I'm gonna be a necromancer soon.

```
    public void test1()
    {
        // Throw an exception for testing purposes
        throw new ArgumentException("test1");
    }

    void test2()
    {
            MethodInfo mi = typeof(Program).GetMethod("test1");
            ((Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), mi))();

    }
```

Comment: Nice idea, but you don't always control the code which calls `.Invoke()`.

Comment: And you don't always know the types of the arguments/result at compile time either.

Answer (score 3):

Anpother sample code which uses exception serialization/deserialization.
It does not require the actual exception type to be serializable.
Also it uses only public/protected methods.

```
    static void PreserveStackTrace(Exception e)
    {
        var ctx = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.CrossAppDomain);
        var si = new SerializationInfo(typeof(Exception), new FormatterConverter());
        var ctor = typeof(Exception).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(SerializationInfo), typeof(StreamingContext) }, null);

        e.GetObjectData(si, ctx);
        ctor.Invoke(e, new object[] { si, ctx });
    }
```

Comment: not require the actual exception type to be serializable ?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a nice clean, modern implementation of some of the other ideas here, tested in .NET 6:

```
public static class ExceptionExtensions
{
    [DoesNotReturn]
    public static void Rethrow(this Exception ex) 
        => ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex).Throw();
}
```

I wanted the value of the `PropertyName` property on `myObject` but this will work just as well when using reflection to call methods (as per OP's problem) or anything else that results in you wanting to re-throw an inner exception.

```
try
{
    object? value = myObject.GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName")?.GetValue(myObject);
}
catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
{
    (ex.InnerException ?? ex).Rethrow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a combination of practices on how to unpack and rethrow the original exceptions in the `AggregateException` combined with the `ExceptionDispatchInfo` class.

```
using ExceptionDispatchInfo = 
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo;

try
{
    try
    {
        task.Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.Flatten()).Throw();
        throw;
    }
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
    throw;
}
```

A note on `throw;` This is also considered best practice after using the `ExceptionDispatchInfo` so the compiler doesn't complain about methods which don't either return or throw. Although its expected to never be reached actually.

I spend the past weeks getting my head around the concept of 'correctly' rethrowing with the AggregateException. This is poorly documented on the microsoft provided docs (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.flatten and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception), because while they do provide some guidance on how to unpack it the practices are fragmented and it doesn't abide the latest 'rethrowing without loosing the stacktrace' practices.

Notes:

- Using the 'normal' `await task;` flow is the recommended pattern in this specific instance and will solve rethrowing of the original exceptions for you.
- The need for unpacking could be considered to be a leaky abstraction.

Comment: What is a "code pad"?

Comment: Good point, let me rephrase it to more clearly state the problem.
To quote from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623/best-practices-for-catching-and-re-throwing-net-exceptions 'So the compiler doesn't complain about methods which don't either return or throw.'