# try- catch. Handling multiple exceptions the same way (or with a fall through)

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

There has already been a question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791390/more-elegant-exception-handling-than-multiple-catch-blocks) which is very similar. Mine is extending that question a bit more. Say you want to catch multiple types of exception but want to handle it the same way, is there a way to do something like switch case ?

```
switch (case)
{
  case 1:
  case 2:

  DoSomething();
  break;
  case 3:
  DoSomethingElse()
  break;

}
```

Is it possible to handle few exceptions the same way . Something like

```
try
{
}
catch (CustomException ce)
catch (AnotherCustomException ce)
{
  //basically do the same thing for these 2 kinds of exception
  LogException();
}
catch (SomeOtherException ex)
{
 //Do Something else
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch multiple Exceptions at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136035/catch-multiple-exceptions-at-once)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Currently there is no language construct to accomplish what you want. Unless the exception all derive from a base exception you need to consider refactoring the common logic to a method and call it from the different exception handlers.

Alternatively you could do as explained in this question:

[Catch multiple Exceptions at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136035/catch-multiple-exceptions-at-once)

Personally I tend to prefer the method-based approach.

Comment: To copy the data to this thread: `catch (Exception ex)            
{                
    if (ex is FormatException || ex is OverflowException)
    {
        WebId = Guid.Empty;
        return;
    }

    throw;
}`

Answer (score 9):

You should really have a BaseCustomException and catch that.

Answer (score 6):

This is [copied from another posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136035/catch-multiple-exceptions-at-once%20source), but I am pulling the code to this thread:

Catch `System.Exception` and switch on the types

```
catch (Exception ex)            
{                
    if (ex is FormatException || ex is OverflowException)
    {
        WebId = Guid.Empty;
        return;
    }

    throw;
}
```

I prefer this to repeating a method call in several catch blocks.

Answer (score 2):

In vb.net, one can use exception filters to say, e.g.

```
  Catch Ex As Exception When TypeOf Ex is ThisException Or TypeOf Ex is ThatException
```

Unfortunately, for whatever reasons, the implementors of C# have as yet refused to allow exception filtering code to be written within C#.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be catching this many custom exceptions,however if you want you can create a common `BaseException` and catch that.

Comment: Why not? There may be 3 custom libraries in effect within the try catch block.

Comment: you're right, in general its perfectly fine to catch as many custom exceptions as you need, in fact its preferred, if you handle them all differently.

Answer (score -5):

I've never actually done this or anything like it, and I don't have access to a compiler for testing purposes but surely something like this would work.  Not sure how to actually do the type comparison or if C# would let you replace the if statements with a case statement.

```
try 
{ 
}
catch (System.Object obj)
{
  Type type;

  type = obj.GetType() ;
  if (type == CustomException || type == AnotherCustomException)
  { 
    //basically do the same thing for these 2 kinds of exception 
    LogException(); 
  } 
  else if  (type == SomeOtherException ex) 
  { 
    //Do Something else 
  }
  else
  {
    // Wasn't an exception to handle here
    throw obj;
  }
}
```

Comment: This might work, but this is not a good solution, since it ignores two very fundamental facts: a) there is a base system Exception class, and you don't need to go all the way down to System.Object; and b) multiple catch statements for different exception classes exist for this very purpose.

Comment: I agree with Allison R on point (a), but in relation to point (b) it seems like criticism for answering the question that was asked.

Comment: Breaking out common functionality into a method and calling it in various `catch()` blocks is the more elegant way to go, since it doesn't require type checking, and makes proper use of native language constructs for exception handling.

Comment: sidenote: the "throw obj;" in the very end should better either be something like only "throw;" or "throw new FooException("blabla", obj);" i guess

Comment: i should probably add a reason to state so too: to preserve the stacktrace inside 'obj' :)