# Throwing an AggregateException in my own code

Tags: .net, exception

How should I go about collecting exceptions and putting them into an [AggregateException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx) to re-throw?

For my specific code, I have a loop and will have zero or more exceptions thrown from a part of the code. I was hoping to just add the new exceptions to the AggregateException as they arise, but the documentation sort of indicates that it should be constructed with all the Exceptions at once (there is no method to add an Exception to the object).

And what about creating a new AE every time and just including the previous AE in the list of exceptions? Seems a hokey way to do it.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Like @bbudge I'm curious as of why you'd want to include old exceptions as part of a new AggregateException instance. It sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: The point was to aggregate exceptions in a loop. Seems like there'd be an API to do that, but in the end I just used a List and created the AggExc at the end.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Are you talking about something like this?

```
var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
foreach (var item in items) {
    try {
        DoSomething(item);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        exceptions.Add(ex);
    }
}

if (exceptions.Count > 0)
    throw new AggregateException(
        "Encountered errors while trying to do something.",
        exceptions
    );
```

Seems like the most logical way to me.

Comment: It's quite often that one finds such short easy to follow and understand examples such as this but when you read the MS docs, often a huge amount of text, you still don't understand them. It's comparable to the Chinese "alphabet" that has over 1000 signs that the latin alphabet can handle with only 20-30 characters

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to add the exceptions to a List until you were ready to throw the AggregateException.

It seems strange to me that you would want to return the old exceptions the next time you create an AggregateException, but if you kept your List around, you could just build a new AggregateException from this.