# How does | (pipe) in pattern matching work?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

You can write:

```
str match { case "foo" | "bar" => ... }
```

At first glance it looks like `|` could be an extractor object, however:

```
str match { case |("foo", "bar") => ... }
```

does not work. (And I can't see how that could be implemented anyway.)

So it is a magic built-in operator?

(I believe I have seen this question on SO before, but it's impossible to search for...)

Comment: Here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384073/catching-multiple-exceptions-at-once-in-scala/6385333#6385333).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes the pipe (`|`) is a built-in for pattern matching (see [the scala language reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)). The Pattern matching section (section 8) defines in section 8.1.11 what is called *Pattern Alternatives*. The definition says:

> A pattern alternative p1 | ... | pn
>   consists of a number of alternative
>   patterns pi . All alternative patterns
>   are type checked with the expected
>   type of the pattern. They may no bind
>   variables other than wildcards. The
>   alternative pattern matches a value v
>   if at least one its alternatives
>   matches v.

So yes, the pipe is a built-in that is context sensitive to pattern matching.

Answer (score 43):

`|` is not implemented in the library, it is interpreted by the Scala compiler. It builds a new pattern that is defined as the disjunction between two subpatterns that don't bind any variable (although the newly formed pattern can itself be bound; i.e., you can write stuff like

```
try { /*...*/ }
catch {
  case e @ (_: IOException | _: IllegalArgumentException) => /*...*/
}
```

and `e` gets as type the most specific supertype of the listed alternatives).