# Matching multiple exception types to the same case

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

When pattern matching an exception with a case statement, is there a more simplified way of matching the same exception to a set of exception types? Instead of this:

```
} catch {
  case e if e.isInstanceOf[MappingException] || e.isInstanceOf[ParseException] =>
```

Something like this would be nice:

```
case e: MappingException | ParseException | SomeOtherException =>
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catching multiple exceptions at once in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384073/catching-multiple-exceptions-at-once-in-scala)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do this:

```
catch {
  case e @ (_: MappingException | _: ParseException | _: SomeOtherException) =>
}
```

If you're trying to save some lines of code and you handle the same types of exceptions regularly, you might consider defining a partial function beforehand to use as a handler:

```
val myHandler: PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit] = {
  case e @ (_: MappingException | _: ParseException | _: SomeOtherException) =>
}

try {
  throw new MappingException("argh!")
} catch myHandler
```

Comment: Is this a special case, or is this a language feature... could you explain how this works/expands outward