# Several "ChildException" catch blocks versius one "Exception" catch block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, readability, catch-block

What's better between several `ChildException` catch blocks and one `Exception` catch block? By *better*, I mean *in a good-practices way*.

To illustrate:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Main.isNonsense1(null)); // false <- bad
    System.out.println(Main.isNonsense2(null)); // NullPointerException <- good
}

// More readable, less precise
public static boolean isNonsense1(String className) {
    try {
        Class.forName(className);
        String.class.getConstructor(String.class);
        className.getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").wait();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

// Less readable, more precise
public static boolean isNonsense2(String className) {
    try {
        Class.forName(className);
        String.class.getConstructor(String.class);
        className.getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").wait();
        return true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If all you want is to return false, then dont't trouble yourself to specialize the cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to this question: [Catch multiple exceptions at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136035/catch-multiple-exceptions-at-once)

The answer there is good.  The key is that if you catch `Exception` then you should handle each of the cases that you are aware of and `throw` all the rest.  That is, simply catching Exception in your example and returning false would **not** be a good idea.  You may inadvertently catch some exception you didn't mean to.

Using your example, here is my suggested code:

```
public static boolean isNonsense2(String className) {
    try {
        Class.forName(className);
        String.class.getConstructor(String.class);
        className.getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").wait();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof ClassNotFoundException
                || e instanceof NoSuchMethodException
                || e instanceof SecurityException
                || e instanceof UnsupportedEncodingException
                || e instanceof NoSuchAlgorithmException
                || e instanceof InterruptedException) {
            return false;
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice idea to use `instanceof` by the way `:)`

Comment: I should also warn that one downside of doing it this way is that the compiler will no longer warn you if you are handling a **checked exception** that cannot be thrown by the code in the `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no complete clear answer. In your case I would code it like this:

```
public static boolean isNonsense1(String className) {
    if(slassname==null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("className must not be null");
    try {
        Class.forName(className);
        String.class.getConstructor(String.class);
        className.getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").wait();
        return true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("provided class " + className + " not found");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For my flavor, throwing a `NullPointerException` is always bad, thats why I throw the `IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in handling the exception (which you should as per best practices) don't bother with the explicit catches. The whole point of being able to handle specific exceptions is to enable you to handle them correctly.