# Catch multiple exceptions at the same time

Tags: vb.net, exception, try-catch

There is sometimes that one want to do the same on two different types of Exception. I searched, but I didn't find anything for VB.NET.

Simple example:

```
Try
    '...
Catch ex As Net.WebException
    'Do something
Catch ex As Net.CookieException
    'Do the same
Catch ex As Exception
    '...
End Try
```

I wonder if there is a way to catch both exceptions at once without needed to repeat code.

Comment: The same way as you do in C#, only the syntax would be a little bit different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136035/catch-multiple-exceptions-at-once

Comment: Hey wait... the second answer has exactly what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/a/136114/1386111

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As seen on [Catch multiple exceptions at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136035/catch-multiple-exceptions-at-once/136114#136114) it can be done this way:

```
Catch ex As Exception When TypeOf ex Is FormatException OrElse TypeOf ex Is OverflowException
```

Comment: In this situation I would have offered ALvin a chance to write his comment as an answer and then accept that, rather than writing it to an answer myself.

Comment: If you are wanting to catch an exception that derives from Exception, you must place it before any that are "plain vanilla" exceptions. I just tested this with FaultException on a SOAP service call.