# Auto Mapper convert from string to Int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper, data-conversion

I am creating a simple MVC4 application

I have a automapper

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.IntphoneNo, 
                  opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Stringphoneno));
```

**IntphoneNo** is of DataType **int** ( IntphoneNo is an variable of my class `Person`)
Source attribute **Stringphoneno** is  of Datatype **string**.

When i am mapping , i am getting follwoing error.

> An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code

But when i am changing the Dataype of **IntphoneNo**  from **int** to **string**  then my program is running successfully.

Unfortunately i cant change the Datatype inmy model

Is theer any way to change Datatupe in mapping ..
Something like below

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.IntphoneNo, 
                  opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Int32(Stringphoneno));
```

After some research  I came one step futher ..
If my StringPhoneNo is = 123456
then follwoing code is working. I dont need to parse it to string

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.IntphoneNo, 
                  opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Stringphoneno));
```

but when my StringPhoneNo is = 12 3456  ( there is a **space after 12**) then  my code is not working.
Is there any way to trim spaces in Stringphoneno (**Stringphoneno** i am geting from webservice)   in automapper.

Something like below..

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.IntphoneNo, 
                  opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Trim(Stringphoneno)));
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise storing phonenumbers(i assume) as ints, you'll lose the international/regional zero prefix numbers. Also, some numbers can be very long. (unless you use a int64) With 11 numbers you got some overflow problems.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I came across the same kind of advice at one point when someone pointed out that we shouldn't be using the money sql type to store money and should instead use decimal. I had a good laugh when I pointed out that we worked in dollars and if we ever had an order where the purchase actually was larger than the money type, I would do the order by hand, we were a small wine company. Not really relevant, just a story I always liked.

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich - But finding a International phone number larger than 10 digit is much easier than scoring an order larger than max money-type :)

Comment: Data type of source is not in my control. I am getting source thru a webservice..

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I agree, just a story I always liked.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>() 
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IntphoneNo, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => int.Parse(src.Stringphoneno)));
```

Here is some sample working code using the map described

```
class SourceClass
{
    public string Stringphoneno { get; set; }
}

class DestinationClass
{
    public int IntphoneNo { get; set; }
}

var source = new SourceClass {Stringphoneno = "8675309"};
var destination = Mapper.Map<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(source);

Console.WriteLine(destination.IntphoneNo); //8675309
```

Comment: you need to capture the exception, maybe the casting to string--> int is not possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136035/catch-multiple-exceptions-at-once to capture the exception!! maybe the string is not a number...

Comment: @user2739679 int.Parse and Int32.Parse are literally the same thing, int maps to Int32. You can place a breakpoint into the lambda expression that's doing the parsing to see what the value is of Stringphoneno to know if you need to format it, strip it of dashes for example, first.

Comment: i cant put a break point ons line inside Mapper.CreateMap. When i am trying to put a break point it is selecting whole area of automapper

Comment: @user2739679 highlight `int.Parse(src.Stringphoneno)` right click on it select insert breakpoint.

Comment: value of **src.stringphoneNo** is a 12345678... but **int.Parse** is not working evenif i change the Datatype of **IntphoneNo** to **string**...

Comment: @user2739679 you're going to have to be specific about what that number is, otherwise your problem is elsewhere. I've posted some working code.

Comment: @ Yuriy Faktorovich.. **StringPhoneNo** i am getting from webservice.. Dont have any control over **StringPhoneNo**.. Only thing i see is DATATYPE of **StringPhoneNo** is string and DATATYPE of **IntPhoneNo** in my model is string..

Comment: @ Yuriy Faktorovich.. to be precise value in **StringPhoneNo ** is 12 23456 ..( there is a space after 12)...

Comment: @user2739679 if it's your model, then you should change it to string. Also you could just replace that space before int.Parse.

Answer (score 12):

The problem you may face is when it is unable to parse the string, one option would be to use a ResolveUsing:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>() 
.ForMember(dest => dest.intphoneno, opts => opts.ResolveUsing(src =>
                double.TryParse(src.strphoneno, out var phoneNo) ? phoneNo : default(double)));
```

Comment: this can be a one-liner (...`src => double.TryParse(src.strphoneno, out var phoneNo) ? phoneNo : default(double)`)

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work any more. `ResolveUsing` was removed, and the recommended alternative in the docs, `MapFrom`, uses expression trees so you cannot use `out` arguments.

Answer (score 3):

`Yuriy Faktorovich`'s solution can be generalized for all `string`s that should be converted to `int`s by defining an extension method for `IMappingExpression` and usage of some custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class StringToIntConvertAttribute : Attribute
{
}

// tries to convert string property value to integer
private static int GetIntFromString<TSource>(TSource src, string propertyName)
{
    var propInfo = typeof(TSource).GetProperty(propertyName);
    var reference = (propInfo.GetValue(src) as string);
    if (reference == null)
        throw new MappingException($"Failed to map type {typeof(TSource).Name} because {propertyName} is not a string);

    // TryParse would be better
    var intVal = int.Parse(reference);
    return intVal;
}

public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> StringToIntMapping<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    var srcType = typeof(TSource);
    foreach (var property in srcType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringToIntConvertAttribute), inherit: false).Length > 0))
    {
        expression.ForMember(property.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetIntFromString(src, property.Name)));
    }

    return expression;
}
```

In order to make this work, the following steps must be performed:

1. Mapping between source and destination must append the mapping extension. E.g.:

   ```
   var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
   {
      // other mappings

      cfg.CreateMap<SrcType, DestType>().StringToIntMapping();
   });
   ```
2. Apply the attribute to all source string properties that must automatically be converted to integer values

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler, but less scalable approach. Whenever you call Mapper.Initialize, remember to call .ToInt() or you'll get a run time error.

```
public class NumberTest
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("".ToInt());
        // 0
        Console.WriteLine("99".ToInt());
        // 99
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int ToInt(this string text)
    {
        int num = 0;
        int.TryParse(text, out num);
        return num;
    }
}

// Use like so with Automapper
.ForMember(dest => dest.WidgetID, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.WidgetID.ToInt()));
```