# Why exception filters are preferable to catching and rethrowing?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, error-handling, .net-4.6

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082069/what-benefit-does-the-new-exception-filter-feature-provide) (What benefit does the new `Exception filter` feature provide?).

The statement:

> Exception filters are preferable to catching and rethrowing because
>   they leave the stack unharmed. If the exception later causes the stack
>   to be dumped, you can see where it originally came from, rather than
>   just the last place it was rethrown.

after doing some testing, I did not see the difference between both, the old and the new, I still see the exception from the place it was **rethrown**. So, or the information is not confirmed, I don't understand the Exception filters( that is why I am asking), or I am doing it wrong. Can you explaing me why this action filter are an advantage?

```
class specialException : Exception
{
   public DateTime sentDateTime { get; } = DateTime.Now;
   public int code { get; } = 0;
   public string emailsToAlert { get; } = "email@domain.com";
}
```

then:

```
        try
        {
            throw new specialException(); //line 16
            throw new Exception("Weird exception");
            //int a = Int32.Parse("fail");
        }
        catch (specialException e) when(e.code == 0)
        {
            WriteLine("E.code 0");
            throw; // <-Line 23
        }
        catch (FormatException e) 
        {
                WriteLine("cond1 " + e.GetBaseException().Message+" "+e.StackTrace);
                throw;
        }
        catch (Exception e) //when (cond2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("cond2! " + e.Message);
                throw;
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: 1. This is a quote from Mads Torgersen who is the PM for C#, you can find it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx).

2. This regards crash-dumps so the specific test is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advantages of exception filtering are more to do with when the filter doesn't match, not when it does match. If you remove all of the `catch` blocks except for the first one, and change the filter on the first `catch` block to `when(e.code != 0)`, then the callstack of the exception would indicate it was thrown on line 16.

The old way of implementing this would be as follows:

```
    try
    {
        throw new specialException(); //line 16
        throw new Exception("Weird exception");
        //int a = Int32.Parse("fail");
    }
    catch (specialException e)
    {
        if(e.code != 0)
        {
            WriteLine("E.code isn't 0");
            return;
        }

        throw;
    }
```

In this case, the call stack will indicate that the exception was thrown at the `throw` statement, rather than on line 16.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Meh, the old way would move the code inside the try {} block into another method so this problem doesn't occur.

Answer (score 3):

I'll give you a good real world example that I've used it for: deadlock retry loops.

Some APIs are nice and have a specific `DeadlockException` sort of thing -- others, like SOAP proxies, not quite. When you don't have one, exception filters are great to avoid needing to rethrow.

```
int retryCount = 0;

while(true)
{
    try
    {
        // do stuff.
        break;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) when(ex.Message == "Deadlock" && ++retryCount < 10)
    {
        // retry up to 10 times.
        continue;
    }
}
```

This saves you from having to throw a wrapper exception if a non-deadlock exception happens, or if the retry limit is hit.