# How to avoid "not all code paths return a value" when using exception filter for logging

Tags: c#, exception, logging

Note: This is a question about whether there is a best-practice / idiomatic way to avoid a particular compiler issue when using exception filters for logging. The question already mentions two different ways it could be done, and the problems with each approach. I'm looking for a better way, if possible.

I'm using an exception filter with a logging method that always returns `false` to log but not catch specific exceptions:

```
public string MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // Do something.
        return "foo";
    }
    catch (SpecificException ex) when (this.LogException(ex))
    {
        // Never hit.
    }
}
```

(Where `bool LogException(SpecificException ex)` always returns `false`.)

The compiler doesn't like this and give me an error: `CS0161 Not all code paths return a value`.

I can avoid this error by adding a `throw;` inside the catch, but the `throw` will never actually be hit.
it ends up looking like a redundant `catch (Exception) { throw; }`, so an inattentive future developer may remove the whole `catch` as a result.

Another way to avoid the compiler error is to use a variable to hold the return value, and move the `return` statement to the end of the method. However, this would involve initialising the variable to a value that would never actually be returned, and again fails to communicate the intention of the code as clearly as I would like.

Is there a better way to avoid this compiler error, that more clearly communicates that the code will never be hit, other than a comment and a redundant `throw;`?

Comment: Maybe add a comment: `when (this.LogException(ex)) // Always false - used exclusively for logging.`?

Comment: `return null;` inside `catch` or after the `try/catch` block would also make it happy.

Comment: ``return default`` after ``try..catch`` bloc

Comment: Maybe it's something that I'm not aware of but is there a difference between what you're currently doing and `catch (SpecificException ex) { this.LogException(ex); throw; }`? This makes it crystal clear that you do need the `catch` block and does the exact same thing, AFAICT.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed There's a subtle difference and it is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638310/why-exception-filters-are-preferable-to-catching-and-rethrowing

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed This is the [Exception Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#exception-filters) feature introduced with C# 6.0.

Comment: @OguzOzgul I know about Exception Filters and I use them all the time. I was just curious if there's an important difference between the two for the OP in this particular case.

Comment: @Ergwun If you're concerned about the StackTrace, check my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no, you will have to satisfy the compilers *static analysis* by either a `throw` or *returning* a result.

You can't turn this off (that I know), or disable the error by a *pragma*.

I think you're in this situation because of misuse of a *language feature*. The compiler fully-expects the *condition* of a `when` to be an *expression* that (may or may not) result in `true`. Moreover, given the limitation of *static analysis*, the compiler in-turn expects the resulting block to be a valid branch (even through you have hardwired it shut) and takes the view it should be a *compilation error*.

I would rethink your design to be predictable without the side-effects, and if you really need to do this, use a comment and the combination of a `throw` or *return* a result (as has been suggested).

Comment: Thanks. Using exception filter side-effects for logging was such a common example for explaining exception filters when they were first introduced I thought it might have become popular, and idiomatic by now. Do you have a recommendation for a re-thought design, or are you advocating reverting to `catch (MyException ex) { Log(ex); throw; }` (plus logging in all other sibling catches)?

Comment: @Ergwun yeah i would expect that to be the more maintainable and predictable approach

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments and the other answer, the proper way *(if you want to keep using Exception Filters)* would be to either throw the exception inside the `catch` block or return `null` and add a comment explaining why the `try/catch` statement is required here:

```
// LogException() always returns false. The `catch` block is used exclusively for logging.
catch (SpecificException ex) when (this.LogException(ex)) { throw; }
```

---

If the purpose of using Exception Filters is to maintain the original StackTrace, you could get around it by using the [`ExceptionDispatchInfo` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo):

```
public string MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        // Do something.
        return "foo";
    }
    catch (SpecificException ex)
    {
        this.LogException(ex);
        ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex).Throw();
        return null; // Redundant. Otherwise, the compiler will complain.
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a handy technique. Thanks.

Comment: You could maintain the original stack trace with simply `throw ;` so what's the purpose of `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex).Throw();`?

Comment: @mason, in this case; not much. But you could use `ExceptionDispatchInfo` to re-throw an exception outside the `catch` block. For instance when you have complex cleanup code.