# java exception string filter

Tags: java, exception, jvm

When throw exception, I found that always included java.lang.exception or javax.ssl.xxxx and so on, I just want to get only messages but not including exception type, how can I do it?

As exception has many types, I can not just filter string start with, is it available to do so?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do. Can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: Maybe `exception.getMessage()` is the method you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch multiple exceptions at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136035/catch-multiple-exceptions-at-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find below a small snippet as demonstration for my comment

```
try {
    int i = 1 / 0;
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("exception  = " + e);
    System.out.println("getMessage = " + e.getMessage());
}
```

output

```
exception  = java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
getMessage = / by zero
```