# What's the point of passing ExceptionDispatchInfo around instead of just the Exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I understand the value of `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e).Throw()` (preserves the original stack trace), but what's the advantage of using `Capture` early and passing the `ExceptionDispatchInfo` around vs. just passing the caught `Exception` around?

As a concrete example, comparing

```
static Exception CaptureException(Action action)
{
  try
  {
    action();
    return null;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    return e;
  }
}

public void Test1()
{
  ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(CaptureException(
       () => throw new IOException("Test")))
    .Throw();
}
```

with

```
static ExceptionDispatchInfo CaptureDispatchInfo(Action action)
{
  try
  {
    action();
    return null;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    return ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e);
  }
}

public void Test2()
{
  CaptureDispatchInfo(() => throw new IOException("Test")).Throw();
}
```

, both give essentially the same stack traces (It's similar for an `async` variation of this.). So, I don't really get why the `ExceptionDispatchInfo` class exists at all, rather than just a combined `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e).Throw()` method.

Comment: It is a runtime implementation detail.  Ideally such classes are `internal`, but it is used in multiple framework assemblies so they did not have a choice but make it public.  That required them to document it in MSDN, it however didn't require them to tell you how it could be useful in your own code.  Lots of framework classes are like this.  I think the key problem it solves is that exception stack traces have thread-affinity, notably a big issue with Control.Invoke().  As long as you write async code using the framework provided mechanisms you'll benefit from its existence.

Comment: If you have a library that holds the raised exception and throws it at a later time this will help preserve the original stacktrace. Theres also a method InternalPreserveStackTrace that can be called which is another workaround (from before ExceptionDispatchInfo existed I think).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're assuming that exceptions are immutable. This is not the case - an exception's StackTrace changes when it's re-thrown.

The purpose of `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture` is to capture a potentially mutating exception's StackTrace at a point in time:

```
void Foo() => throw new InvalidOperationException ("foo");

Exception original = null;
ExceptionDispatchInfo dispatchInfo = null;
try
{
    try
    {
        Foo();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        original = ex;
        dispatchInfo = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture (ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex2)
{
    // ex2 is the same object as ex. But with a mutated StackTrace.
    Console.WriteLine (ex2 == original);  // True
}

// So now "original" has lost the StackTrace containing "Foo":
Console.WriteLine (original.StackTrace.Contains ("Foo"));  // False

// But dispatchInfo still has it:
try
{
    dispatchInfo.Throw ();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine (ex.StackTrace.Contains ("Foo"));   // True
}
```

Comment: Will ex2 stack trace be in its initial state if we use "throw" instead of "throw ex"?

Comment: A .NET Fiddle of this https://dotnetfiddle.net/HnuVvO

Comment: @Razor23Donetsk Almost. Where the original stack trace showed the line number of the `Foo();` call, ex2 will show the line number of the `throw;` call instead. Much better than the `throw ex;` option which completely destroys everything before it, but `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex).Throw();` is better because it shows both the line where the exception was caught and the line where it was rethrown. So I never use just `throw;` anymore.

Answer (score 6):

ExceptionDispatchInfo is used to preserve the stack trace after an Exception is thrown, allowing you to catch that exception, not throwing it immediately (as part of a catch), and to raise such exception on a later point in the future.

I found a good example of this on 
https://thorarin.net/blog/post/2013/02/21/Preserving-Stack-Trace.