# Understanding End of stack trace comment in .NET stack traces

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to correctly read stack traces generated by ASP.NET Core. I don't have a problem finding the cause of an exception. But I see the comment `--- End of stack trace from previous location ---` over and over:

[image: stack trace]

Maybe I misunderstood something fundamental about how stack traces are generated. But to my knowledge, the `--- End of stack trace ...` string is added when using `ExceptionDispatchInfo` to rethrow errors but maintaining the original stack trace:

```cs
ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e).Throw();
```

(Sort of a hybrid between `throw` and `throw e`)

When looking at the ASP.NET Core source code, it looks to just throw exceptions normally. Can anyone explain why the stack trace is formatted as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> When looking at the ASP.NET Core source code, it looks to just throw exceptions normally.

But if you look at the places you have in the provided stack trace then you'll see `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e).Throw()`.

E.g. in [ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ResourceInvoker.cs#L963):

```cs
catch (Exception exception)
{
    _resourceExecutedContext = new ResourceExecutedContextSealed(_resourceExecutingContext!, _filters)
    {
        ExceptionDispatchInfo = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception),
    };
}
```

The reason for using `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture()` is well explained in [What's the point of passing ExceptionDispatchInfo around instead of just the Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723327/whats-the-point-of-passing-exceptiondispatchinfo-around-instead-of-just-the-exc)

Comment: My conclusion here: You are right and I am blind  I was looking here primarily: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ControllerActionInvoker.cs#L492. Which has a throw statement. But it also has the dispatcher exactly as you say. Thank you!