# C# Why was exception raised inside try-catch block?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception, webforms

I have this code in ASP.NET form:

```
bool cont = true;
int i = 0;

while (cont)
{
    try
    {
        JToken token = tempJSON["temperature"]["tool" + i];
        temperature.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Structures.Temperature>(token.ToString()));
        i++;
    }
    catch(NullReferenceException ex) { pokracovat = false; }
}
 
return new TemperatureAndState(temperature, state);
```

After running code, the program raises a NullReferenceException inside try catch. How it is possible. I thought that if an exception is raised in a try block the program will call catch and then continue.

Error:

[image: error image]

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630437/try-catch-block-not-catching-exception

Comment: This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921984/stop-visual-studio-from-breaking-on-exception-in-tasks

Comment: If you are debugging, then Visual Studio will always stop on an error so you (the developer) will know it's there. However, when not debugging, this won't happen.

Comment: Thank you to everyone

Answer (score 0):

When debugging, the compiler will stop and Visual Studio will break on the error that occurred, even though it has a catch.

Don't worry, this will never happen when running the application normally.

> Note: If the exception thrown inside your `try` block is not handled in the `catch` block, the application will crash, so it'd be great if you add a `catch(Exception)` block, so if a non-prevented exception occurs, you treat it accordingly.