# how to throw an exception from a class back to the form that called it

Tags: c#, class, exception

Hello I have a regular WinForm that calls this:

```
private void childDirectoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         SQL.createTable("childDirectory"); //THIS LINE
     }
     catch(SystemException ecp)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ecp.Message));
     }
}
```

and have a class named "SQL". The C# class cannot throw a messageBox to the user, only Console.WriteLine:

```
static public void createTable(string tableToCreate)
        {
            try
            {
                .
                .
                .
                .
            }
            catch (SqlException exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Database not created: " + exp.Message, "Error");
            }
        }
```

How can I throw this SqlExecption back in the Form.cs call? Sorry if my wording is wrong, hopefully you can understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    static public void createTable(string tableToCreate)
    {
        try
        {
            .
            .
            .
            .
        }
        catch (SqlException exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Database not created: " + exp.Message, "Error");
            throw exp;
        }
    }
```

And catch it with:

```
 private void childDirectoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
          SQL.createTable("childDirectory"); //THIS LINE
     }
     catch(SystemException ecp)
     {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ecp.Message));
     }
     catch (SqlException exp)
     {               

     }
 }
```

But unless it is necessary you don't need to catch exception in called method if you catch it in calling method.

Comment: Instead of `throw exp;` it should just be `throw;` which preserves the stack trace of the original exception

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to bubble up the exception I would suggest you simply don't catch it in the createTable method - instead add an exception handler for `SqlException` iny your `childDirectoryToolStripMenuItem_Click` method.

```
private void childDirectoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         SQL.createTable("childDirectory"); //THIS LINE
     }
     catch (SqlException ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Database not created: " + ex.Message);
     }
     catch(SystemException ecp)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(string.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ecp.Message));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just let the error propogate up to the windows form, and avoid a double catch? You could do the logging there.

However, if you do indeed want to do it this way, then you would just call `throw`. This will simply rethrow the exception. The plus to this method over `throw exp` is that it will keep the original stack trace, and not mislead any debugging. An already vetted explanation for this can be found at: [What is the proper way to re-throw an exception in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178456/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-throw-an-exception-in-c)