# Collapse sub nodes to list using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a class that defines the xml and another class that defines the candidate and another class that it is a list of the class candidate.

I am trying to create dynamically the list according to number of nodes that I have in the xml.

I have tried all kind of variations and nothing worked, until the nodes Candidates I got all the information but the CandidateList came null all the time.

```
public class Candidate
{
}

public class CandidateList : List<Candidate>
{
}

public class Request
{
    public CandidateList CandidateList { get; set; }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Requests>
  <Request>
    <MidaClientID>1040</MidaClientID>
    <!--elided other elements-->
    <OrderDescription></OrderDescription>
    <Candidates>
      <Candidate>
        <QuestNum>6</QuestNum>
        <!--elided other elements-->
        <EventNum>012</EventNum>
      </Candidate>
      <Candidate>
        <QuestNum>6</QuestNum>
         <!--elided other elements-->
        <EventNum>012</EventNum>
      </Candidate>
    </Candidates>
  </Request>
</Requests>
```

```
try
{
    IEnumerable<Request> req = from r in input.Descendants("Request")
    select new Request()
    {
        MidaClientID = (int)r.Element("MidaClientID") != 0 ? (int)r.Element("MidaClientID") : 0,
        Password = (string)r.Element("MidaClientPassword") != null ? (string)r.Element("MidaClientPassword") : string.Empty,
        ClientNum = (int)r.Element("ClientNum") != 0 ? (int)r.Element("ClientNum") : 0,
        ClientName = (string)r.Element("ClientName") != null ? (string)r.Element("ClientName") : string.Empty,
        ContactNum = (int)r.Element("ContactNum") != 0 ? (int)r.Element("ContactNum") : 0,
        ContactFirstName = (string)r.Element("ContactFirstName") != null ? (string)r.Element("ContactFirstName") : string.Empty,
        ContactLastName = (string)r.Element("ContactLastName") != null ? (string)r.Element("ContactLastName") : string.Empty,
        ContactEmail = (string)r.Element("ContactEmail") != null ? (string)r.Element("ContactEmail") : "",
        OrderID = (int)r.Element("OrderID") != 0 ? (int)r.Element("OrderID") : 0,
        OrderDesc = (string)r.Element("OrderDescription") != null ? (string)r.Element("OrderDescription") : "",
        CandidateList = (from i in input.Root.Element("Candidates").Elements("Candidate")
            select new Candidate()
            {
                QuestNum = (int)r.Element("QuestNum") != 0 ? (int)r.Element("QuestNum") : 0,
                CandNum = (int)r.Element("CandNum") != 0 ? (int)r.Element("CandNum") : 0,
                EventNum = (int)r.Element("EventNum") != 0 ? (int)r.Element("EventNum") : 0,
                EventDate = (string)(r.Element("EventDate")) == string.Empty ?
                            DateTime.Today : (DateTime)(r.Element("EventDate")),
                EventTime = (string)(r.Element("EventTime")) == string.Empty ?
                            DateTime.Now : (DateTime)(r.Element("EventTime")),
                CandFirstName = (string)r.Element("CandFirstName") != null ? (string)r.Element("CandFirstName") : string.Empty,
                CandLastName = (string)r.Element("CandLastName") != null ? (string)r.Element("CandLastName") : string.Empty,
                CandPhone1 = (string)r.Element("CandPhone1") != null ? (string)r.Element("CandPhone1") : string.Empty,
                CandPhone2 = (string)r.Element("CandPhone2") != null ? (string)r.Element("CandPhone2") : string.Empty,
                CandPhone3 = (string)r.Element("CandPhone3") != null ? (string)r.Element("CandPhone3") : string.Empty,
                CandAttach1 = (string)r.Element("CandAttach1") != null ? (string)r.Element("CandAttach1") : string.Empty,
                CandAttach2 = (string)r.Element("CandAttach2") != null ? (string)r.Element("CandAttach2") : string.Empty,
                CandAttach3 = (string)r.Element("CandAttach3") != null ? (string)r.Element("CandAttach3") : string.Empty
            }) as CandidateList
    };
    return req.ToList();
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: I think that now it is cleaner and hope it is still clear

Comment: Suggestion on how to re-throw exceptions: [What is the proper way to re-throw an exception in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178456/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-throw-an-exception-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for tidying up the question - having to scroll horizontally is a bit of a nightmare (will edit to show).

Anyway - it seems that your primary problem is the bit where you select your Candidates node:

```
CandidateList = (from i in input.Root.Element("Candidates").Elements("Candidate")
```

The problem being that the linq query does not produce a `CandidateList` instance.  One way to do that will be to add a range constructor to your `CandidateList` type and feed the linq query to it.  Also - I think the `input.Root` is wrong.

```
public class CandidateList : List<Candidate>{
  public CandidateList() {}
  public CandidateList(IEnumerable<Candidate> range) : base(range) {}
}
```

```
//.. in 'new Request{' block
select new Candidate {
  // ... other members elided
  CandidateList = new CandidateList(
    (from i in r.Element("Candidates").Elements("Candidate") 
    select new Candidate()     
    {   
      //...all the Candidate members
    })
  ) //<-- end of the constructor call
}
```

You'll also need to drop the `as CandidateList` from the end of that query after moving it into the constructor, otherwise you'll either get an empty CandidateList or, possibly an `ArgumentNullException` from the `List<T>` base class of `CandidateList`. Notice that I've change the `from`; since you want the `Candidates/Candidate` nodes for the current `Requests/Request`, which is given by `r`.

Finally - all your property assignments to the `Candidate` object are coming from `r` - you need to change those to `i` (the product of the inner Linq statement).

Comment: Still getting the CandidateList as null

Comment: Changed that as you wrote and the line that refers to the elements and still null                                                                 the line:from i in r.Element("Candidates").Elements("Candidate")

Comment: Now i am getting the error :Value cannot be null and the stack trace is leading me to the line :  public CandidateList(IEnumerable<Candidate> range) : base(range){} , can you please explain the meaning of this line

Comment: It's the constructor to build a `CandidateList` from an `IEnumerable<Candidate>`, for which we've used your original Linq query (slightly modified) - I don't think you got rid of the `as CandidateList` from the end of your inner query - the reason I say that is because Linq queries never return `null`; only empty enumerables.  You *cannot use `as CandidateList` because the linq query is not a `CandidateList`*.  Indeed if you look at my answer I say that you'll get this exact problem if you leave it there :)

Comment: First thank you for your patience, i want to learn linq very well so you are giving allot of new information, Second i am still getting the exception -   Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: element

Comment: CandidateList = new CandidateList((from i in r.Element("Candidates").Elements("Candidate")                                                             select new Candidate()                                                                               {                                                                                                                                                                     }))

Comment: @DannySpivak do you have any `Request`s that *don't* have a `Candidates` node?  Please note - also - I've just noticed that you're also selecting from `r` on each candidate - instead of `i`

Comment: No, for the time being i have an xml file that i am debugging with him

Comment: thank you very much everything is working excellent,and again thank you for the patience

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly instantiate the `CandidateList` property.

```
var doc = XElement.Load(@"path-to-xml");
var result = doc.Descendants("Request")
    .Select(RequestSelector);

private Request RequestSelector(XElement elem)
{
    var request  = new Request();
    // Fill properties here
    request.Candidates = new CandidateList();
    request.Candidates.AddRange(elem.Descendants("Candidate").Select(CandidateSelector));
    return request;
}

private Candidate CandidateSelector(XElement elem)
{
    var candidate = new Candidate();
    candidate.CandFirstName = elem.Element("CandFirstName").Value;
    // Fill other properties here
    return candidate;
}
```

Comment: you gave an idea for developing my code late on in the future,thank you