# Inside Try/Catch (Second Try/Catch Is Inside A Method)

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

Please see the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            mymethod();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)//First catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void mymethod()
    {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 0;
        try
        {
            int c = a / b;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)//Second catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            //int c = a / b;
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I want to force the first `catch` to execute after the second `catch` executes! How can I force the above to run and show the second `catch` error? **I want to see the same `ex.ToString()` for both `catch` blocks.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of throwing a new exception, just rethrow the existing one:

```
private void mymethod()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 0;
    try
    {
        int c = a / b;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)//Second catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        //int c = a / b;
        throw; // change here
    }
}
```

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178456/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-throw-an-exception-in-c) for details on how to properly rethrow an exception.

**Update**: Another, but slightly less preferred way to capture the `mymethod` exception and provide those details to the click handler would be to pass the exception along wrapped in a new one:

```
private void mymethod()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 0;
    try
    {
        int c = a / b;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)//Second catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        //int c = a / b;
        throw new Exception("mymethod exception", ex); // change here
    }
}
```

Again, the post I linked to has more detail.