# AX 2012 R3 Visual Studio project C# parsing errors

Tags: c#, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am writing a wrapper for `SSHnet dll` from renci (https://sshnet.codeplex.com/), so I can fetch files from a `sFTP` server via Dynamics AX periodically.

When I catch errors in `C#` project for example in a try catch statement how can I parse the error message back to AX?

Options I thought of;

1. Should I put the *error* message in a string variable and read the `string` in Dynamics AX?
2. Write *errors* to the event log on the AOS / client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to pass error to AX is a rethrow it in C#

```
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    // Do special cleanup, logging etc.
    throw;
}
```

and catch it in AX

```
catch (Exception::CLRError)
{
     ex = ClrInterop::getLastException();
     if (ex != null)
     {
        ex = ex.get_InnerException();
        if (ex != null)
        {
            error(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aliaksandr,

Thank you very much!

Comment: rethrow should be written as `throw;` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178456/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-throw-an-exception-in-c and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2007/02/15/throw-e-vs-throw/