# Why is my custom exception wrapped in System.Exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I believe I'm following the correct process to implement a custom exception, but the exception arrives in the catch block wrapped in a System.Exception, so the handling for my custom exception doesn't execute.

I create the custom exception class (following examples found online):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
namespace La.Di.Da
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MyCustomException : Exception
    {
        public MyCustomException()
            : base()
        {
        }

        public MyCustomException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }

    ...
}
```

I throw the exception, from a lower point in the stack:

```
...
if (up == down)
{
    throw new MyCustomException("Things are topsy-turvy.");
}
...
```

The exception is caught at an intermediate try-catch. I know such catching-logging-throwing is wrong practice but this code is in an existing method that's called a lot in this application, and regression testing the entire application for my small change isn't an option. Anyway, this catch-throw isn't causing the problem: The exception arrives in this catch already as a System.Exception wrapping my custom exception.

```
try
{
    DoSomeStuff(();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogManager.Instance.LogException(ex);
    throw;
}
finally
{
    DoSomeCleanup();
}
```

I have code to catch the custom exception at the next catch up the stack. But the exception arrives as a System.Exception wrapping the custom exception, so my custom exception handling doesn't get executed.

```
...
try
{
    CallAMethod();
}
catch MyCustomException(ex)
{
    LogManager.Instance.LogException(ex);
    ShowErrorMessage(ex.Message);
}
catch Exception(ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

I believe the exception I'm throwing shouldn't be wrapped, so I must be doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your error, but couldn't (ie I was able to catch the re-thrown custom exception as it's original type). You'll have to give us more context...

Comment: I am also not able to recreate your scenario. In my test, the control rightly goes to the `MyCustomException` catch blow.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyCustomException : Exception
```

That code means your class is extending the `Exception` class. So when you throw it, and catch it with an `Exception` catch, it is held as that base class. You can always cast it back to `MyCustomException`.

If by wrapping, you mean that your custom exception is included as an inner exception, it's likely because of your re-throwing the exception.

It also may be how your second set of try catches function. I haven't seen that style before so it may be valid, but try it written as

```
catch(MyCustomException ex){
...
}
```

instead

Comment: Regarding the style, that's our standard. We have StyleCop enforcing it.

Comment: If you want to re-throw an exception, just use `throw` instead of `throw ex`, otherwise you will mess up your stack trace. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178456/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-throw-an-exception-in-c

Answer (score 1):

### Why?

An exception handler will catch any exception that is *or is derived from* the specified exception type.

For example

```
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    //Handler
}
```

...will catch everything.  Meanwhile

```
catch (System.ApplicationException e)
{
    //Handler
}
```

...will catch all exceptions that derive from [ApplicationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception(v=vs.110).aspx).  This includes all of these:

`Microsoft.JScript.NoContextException, Microsoft.JScript.ReturnOutOfFinally, System.Reflection.InvalidFilterCriteriaException, System.Reflection.TargetException, System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException, System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException, System.Threading.WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException`

This is exactly why you should never catch `System.Exception`.  It catches everything!

This is also why exception handlers are declared in order from specific to general-- if the general handler were first, none of the other handlers would ever fire.

### How to fix

Get rid of the `catch (System.Exception)` if you can.

### Workaround

If you can't get rid of your `catch (System.Exception)` block, you can use a [when filter](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/c-6-0-exception-filter-and-when-keyword) so that it will ignore your custom exception, like this:

```
catch (System.Exception e) when (!(e is MyCustomException))
{
    //Handler
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your query, but generally, your Custom exception should include these 3 constructors (may be you already have it)

[Exception best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions)

> Use at least the three common constructors when creating your own exception classes: the default constructor, a constructor that takes a string message, and a constructor that takes a string message and an inner exception.

This will allow you to chain exceptions, i.e., the `InnerException` property can contain another exception object, whose `InnerException` can contain another one, and so on.

Also, your handler which has just the `throw` statement is the correct way (in most cases), as it would [preserve the stack trace info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex).