# Auto Mapper Mapping Exception in 2.2.1.0

Tags: c#, automapper

I have used Automapper 2.2.1.0 in my C# project and sometimes in production server, it's giving Error.

> Type:  AutoMapperMappingException
>   Message:
>   Mapping types:
>   IDataReader -> List`1
>   System.Data.IDataReader -> 
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1
>   [[Repository.AgriAdvisor, Repository, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Below is my code

```
Sqlhelper _helper = new Sqlhelper(ObjConnection);
List<T> varObj = null;
try
{
    var sqlrdr = _helper.GetReaderByCmdWithParameter(spName, parameters);
    using (_helper)
    {
        if (sqlrdr.HasRows)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, List<T>>());
            varObj = Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<T>>(sqlrdr);
        }
    }
    return varObj;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

kindly help me why this error is coming and it's not coming always sometimes it's gives error and maximum number of times it's working fine.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but best practice nevertheless - you're [loosing the stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178464/2974754) of your exception, use `throw;` instead.

Comment: AutoMapper is not a full-featured ORM. It does have `AutoMapper.Data` for mapping data readers, but personally I'd still go with Dapper instead, which is explicitly designed as an ORM.

Comment: Thank you everyone ...actually, the project is in live stage and I cannot change the DLL files nor the architecture of it. Is there anything else that I can do?