# Retry Policy for LINQ to SQL Stored Procedure calls

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I know this has been asked several times before, but I thought I may have a different solution; however, I need some help to get it to work.

The idea:
Business Layer calls a Data layer function.  The data layer function wraps the call to the database context's stored procedure function in a retry policy.  Essentially, I want the LINQ tool to import and manage the actual call to the stored procedure, but I wish it would wrap the logic with some retry policy for retry-able errors.

Much of this concept is taken from [What is good C# coding style for catching SQLException and retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821668/what-is-good-c-sharp-coding-style-for-catching-sqlexception-and-retrying), however, this appears to only work for LINQ to SQL commands, not calling stored procedure functions generated in the DBML.

Old method:

```
Sub BLFunctionWithoutRetry()
    Using DB as CustDataContext
        DB.sp_GetCustomers()
    End Using
End Sub
```

New Logic with Retry:

```
Sub BLFunctionWithRetry()
    GetCustomers()
End Sub

Function GetCustomers() As List(Of Customer)
    Return Retry(Of List(Of Customer))(sp_GetCustomers())
End Function

Function Retry(Of T)(FunctionToCall As Func(Of T)) As T
    Dim Attempt As Integer = 0
    While True
        Try
            Using DB as MyDataContext
                DB.FunctionToCall()
            End Using
        Catch ex as SQLException
            If Retryable() Then Attempt += 1
            If Attempt >= Max Or Not Retryable() Then Throw
        End Try
    End While

Function Retryable() As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

This is the general idea; however, I need help writing the Retry function above. I am getting the obvious error `FunctionToCall() is not a member of 'MyDataContext'`.  Additaionlly, I dont know how to write this so it will work for any stored procedure with any length of input parameters.

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: Sq, what isn't working for you. Does Linq-to-SQL throw a different type of exception? Does it break the context?

Comment: Does it maybe have something to do with the fact that your stored procedures have not return type and require `Action<T>` instead of `Func<T>` or vice versa?

Comment: @jesse Thanks for the edit. The exception is correct, and I'm not sure what you mean by breaking the context. The Retry function needs work, not sure if it's `Action <T>` or not, that's where I'm stuck. -Thanks

Comment: So what exactly is the exception message you're getting?

Comment: @jessehouwing The problem I am having is with the execution of a function defined by input on an instance of the context.  I have updated the signature for Retry above and expanded on the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After needing to implement something like this, I went ahead and made it a library: https://github.com/daveaglick/LinqToSqlRetry (MIT licensed and available on NuGet). It's a standard .NET library, so it should be usable from VB as well (though my examples below are C# - forgive me for not knowing VB all that well).

You can retry `SubmitChanges()` calls by writing `SubmitChangesRetry()` instead:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())
{
  context.Items.InsertOnSubmit(new Item { Name = "ABC" });
  context.SubmitChangesRetry();
}
```

You can also retry queries by using the `Retry()` extension method:

```
using(var context = new MyDbContext())
{
  int count = context.Items.Where(x => x.Name == "ABC").Retry().Count();
}
```

The specific retry logic is controllable by policies. Under the hood, the retry mechanism looks like:

```
int retryCount = 0;
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        return func();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TimeSpan? interval = retryPolicy.ShouldRetry(retryCount, ex);
        if (!interval.HasValue)
        {
            throw;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(interval.Value);
    }
    retryCount++;
}
```

Understand that the function in the call to `func()` and the `retryPolicy` object are provided based on usage. This just gives you an idea what's going on during the retry loop. Just look in the repository for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Some times the answer is in the question, quite literally in this case.  The function Retry in [What is good C# coding style for catching SQLException and retrying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821668/what-is-good-c-sharp-coding-style-for-catching-sqlexception-and-retrying) actually works for stored procedure calls too!  For those still working in VB, here is the code:

```
Public Class DatabaseHelper

    Private Enum RetryableSqlErrors
        SqlConnectionBroken = -1
        SqlTimeout = -2
        SqlOutOfMemory = 701
        SqlOutOfLocks = 1204
        SqlDeadlockVictim = 1205
        SqlLockRequestTimeout = 1222
        SqlTimeoutWaitingForMemoryResource = 8645
        SqlLowMemoryCondition = 8651
        SqlWordbreakerTimeout = 30053
    End Enum


    Public Shared Sub Retry(Of T As {DataContext, New})(retryAction As Action(Of T), ByVal MaxAttempts As Integer, ByVal Delay As Integer)
        Dim retryCount = 0
        Using ctx = New T()
            While True
                Try
                    retryAction(ctx)
                    Exit Sub
                Catch ex As SqlException
                    If Not [Enum].IsDefined(GetType(RetryableSqlErrors), ex.Number) Then
                        Throw
                    End If

                    retryCount += 1
                    If retryCount > MaxAttempts Then
                        Throw
                    End If

                    Thread.Sleep(If(ex.Number = CInt(RetryableSqlErrors.SqlTimeout), Delay * 5, Delay))
                End Try
            End While
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
        target = value
        Return value
    End Function
End Class
```

Then to call a stored proc:

```
Dim results = New YourType
Retry(Of YourDataContext)(Function(ctx) InlineAssignHelper(Of YourType)(results, ctx.YourStoredProc("Your", "Proc", "Inputs", 1).First), 3, .5)
Return results
```

Slight change from the original: I decided to use only 1 delay value, and multiplied it by 5 for a time out.

Thank you to David Clarke for the original post!  Very impressive function.

Comment: More ***SQL Error Codes*** for retrying https://github.com/marinoscar/CommonHelpers/blob/master/SqlErrorCodes.cs