# How can I use this method to reuse my try/catch?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, delegates

I found this method (function?) from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4822976/2315112) and I'm unsure how I'm to use it.  I'd like to use it to catch connectivity issues to my DB (over a wireless network) and retry or throw other exceptions.  My application only has a couple of database accessing functions so I was about to just copy and paste everything but I don't want to have to update every function 10 times if I need to change something.

Method I want to use:

```
        private void Retry<T>(Action<T> retryAction) where T : DataContext, new()
    {
        var retryCount = 0;
        using (var ctx = new T())
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                try
                {
                    retryAction(ctx);
                    break;
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(RetryableSqlErrors), ex.Number))
                        throw;

                    retryCount++;
                    if (retryCount > MAX_RETRY) throw;

                    Thread.Sleep(ex.Number == (int)RetryableSqlErrors.Timeout ?
                                                            longWait : shortWait);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Example of functions I want to pass to it:

```
public async Task<List<EmployeeDisplay>> GetInspectorsAsync()
    {
        using (M1Context m1 = new M1Context())
        {

            var q = (from a in m1.Employees
                     where (a.lmeTerminationDate == null)
                     && (a.lmeInspectorEmployee == -1)
                     orderby a.lmeEmployeeName
                     select new EmployeeDisplay
                     {
                         EmployeeID = a.lmeEmployeeID,
                         EmployeeName = a.lmeEmployeeName.ToUpper().Trim()
                     });

            return await q.ToListAsync();
        }

    }


       public async Task<List<Reason>> GetScrapReasonsAsync()
    {
        using (M1Context m1 = new M1Context())
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("getting scrap reasons");
            var q = (from a in m1.Reasons
                     where a.xarReasonType.Trim().Equals("S")
                     select a);

            return await q.ToListAsync();

        }
    }
```

Comment: why would you write the method 10 times when all you need to do is create a custom class where you can access it and or make a static class and then call the method from the 10 said different places.. I hope I am understanding your question correctly..

Comment: This is a pretty generic retry method for handling `SqlException` what else would you want to do with it?

Comment: You're understanding correctly MethodMan, and the answer is not a good one.  Just needed to get something done and in my lack of experience I only knew one quick and dirty way to get it done.  Luckily I have you guys to help me out!  As for what else I'd want to do with it, I'm not sure at the moment but I hate they idea of having duplicate methods floating around when I can just create a custom class for it.

Comment: Oh also, I want to eventually add some logging functionality so I probably want to do some of that in this catch block.

Answer (score 0):

To to use the method you need to do the following

1. Your Context

[image]

2. Your Retry Method

[image]

3. Your Do Stuff method

[image]

4. Enum

[image]

Comment: I'm partially able to follow this, but I'm a little lost on how to call the method.  I'm assuming that MyRetryActionMethod() in your example would be like the GetInspectorsAsync() method from mine.  Do you think you could expand a bit on the //Do Stuff portion of your example?  I'm not familiar with this procedure of creating the method as you did above: MyRetryActionMethod = (mycontext ) => { //Do Stuff };

Comment: I have added example for you