# Getting the correct Exception type out of a call to Invoke (reflection)

Tags: .net, reflection, exception, invoke

In our integration project we are dynamically delegating to a series of specific Processor objects using Reflection.

```
var genericType = typeof(IMessageProcessor<>).MakeGenericType(parseResponse.DomainMessage.GetType());

var miProcessMessage = genericType.GetMethod("ProcessMessage");
miProcessMessage.Invoke(processor, new object[] { parseResponse.DomainMessage });
```

Now, in certain situations, one of the processors needs to throw a specific Exception, in this case when he doesn't find a file in the expected location.

```
throw new ResourceNotFoundException(string.Format("Could not find file {0}", filePath));
```

Our processor wants to check on this exception to determine whether processing needs to be retried or aborted (based on a time-based mechanism, which is not relevant here).

```
catch(ResourceNotFoundException ex)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

The problem is that the invoke apparently "swallows" the specific ResourceNotFoundException and rethrows a System.Exception saying "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Is there any way of preserving the fact through Reflection that a ResourceNotFoundException was actually thrown and not an Exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MethodBase.Invoke(Object, Object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx) wraps any exception thrown by the invoked method in a [`TargetInvocationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception.aspx). You can access the inner exception and either process it directly, or rethrow it to be processed further up the stack as in the following example:

```
var genericType = typeof(IMessageProcessor<>).MakeGenericType(parseResponse.DomainMessage.GetType());
var miProcessMessage = genericType.GetMethod("ProcessMessage");
try {
    miProcessMessage.Invoke(processor, new object[] { parseResponse.DomainMessage });
catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
{
    throw ex.InnerException;
}
```

Note however that this will replace the inner exception's stack trace. A (technically unsupported) way of preserving the stack trace is described in [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555599/how-to-rethrow-the-inner-exception-of-a-targetinvocationexception-without-losing/4557183#4557183).

Comment: Thats what I found out as well yeah.  Funny thing is it works for inbuilt Exception types such as SqlException or TransactionException, these are not wrapped and can be directly handled in their own exception block. For others, we need to look at the InnerException type.