# How to correctly unwrap a TargetInvocationException?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, exception

I am writing a component which, at the top level, invokes a method via reflection. To make my component easier to use, I'd like to catch any exceptions thrown by the invoked method and unwrap them.

Thus, I have something like:

```
try { method.Invoke(obj, args); }
catch (TargetInvocationException ex) {
    throw ex.InnerException;
}
```

However, this blows away the inner exception stack trace. I can't use just `throw` here (because I'm rethrowing a different exception object). What can I do in my catch block to make sure that the original exception type, message, and stack trace all get through?

Comment: No need to place tags in your question title. Tagging correctly is sufficient.

Comment: Why do you think it makes it easier to confuse the stack trace?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17091351/947986), starting with .NET 4.5 you can use the `ExceptionDispatchInfo` class to unwrap the inner exception.

```cs
try
{
    someMethod.Invoke();
}
catch(TargetInvocationException ex)
{
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
}
```

Comment: Should be marked as the answer. Had the same problem and it was driving me crazy.