# Detect when running inside a catch block

Tags: c#, catch-block

How do I detect when the currently-executing code is being called from within a catch block?

```
void SomeFunction()
{
    // how do I detect whether I am being called from within a catch block?
}
```

EDIT:

For those asking, I wanted to implement a class like this, never mind the error bubbling logic: On writing this code sample, I'm getting a compiler error "A throw statement with no arguments is not allowed outside of a catch clause" so that kinda destroys my idea anyway.

```
public class ErrorManager {

    public void OnException(Exception ex) {
        LogException(ex);
        if (IsInsideCatchBlockAlready()) {
            // don't destroy the stack trace, 
            // but do make sure the error gets bubbled up
            // through the hierarchy of components
            throw; 
        } else {
            // throw the error to make it bubble up 
            // through the hierarchy of components
            throw ex; 
        }
    }

    void LogException(Exception ex) {
        // Log the exception
    }

    bool IsInsideCatchBlockAlready() {
        // How do I implement this?
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't. And if you think you need to, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: throw new Exception(); and see what happens next :)
Just kidding.

Comment: Explain why you need this and we can solve this XY problem for you. Alternatively, make your method throw exceptions on demand by introducing a `bool throwIfNotFound` parameter or whatever it is you want to accomplish. A method should never rely on whoever calls it or how, that's what parameters are for.

Comment: Can you can up with some [real] "sample" code to show us the reasoning behind your solution? Perhaps we can aid in finding a better solution

Comment: I suppose the hacky `bool caught = true` is out of the question?

Comment: Edited the question to include more info, thanks everybody

Comment: So your actual question is _"How can I rethrow an exception without losing the stack trace?"_? Then see [In C#, how can I rethrow InnerException without losing stack trace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383/in-c-how-can-i-rethrow-innerexception-without-losing-stack-trace).

Comment: You could also opt for a combination of `AppDomain.FirstChanceException` and `AppDomain.UnhandledException`. All that come through the first, but not the last, have been caught already.

Comment: @CodeCaster, +1 for writing "A method should never rely on whoever calls it or how, that's what parameters are for."

Comment: If you're trying to have a common exception handler, you can write a method & call that from any `catch` clause.  The `throw` by itself to rethrow the exception needs to be in the `catch` block, however.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, because you are almost certainly headed down a very bad path.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.  There is no way to know if, should you throw an exception, it would be caught or crash the program.  You could *potentially* make a *guess* at compile time with a code analysis tool, but that wouldn't be an option while the code is running.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do that.

There might be some sneaky way by analyzing the generated (IL) code, but I am pretty sure you don't want that.

This is the IL from a standard Console application catching an exception:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       34 (0x22)
  .maxstack  1
  IL_0000:  nop
  .try
  {
    IL_0001:  nop
    IL_0002:  ldstr      "OK"
    IL_0007:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000c:  nop
    IL_000d:  nop
    IL_000e:  leave.s    IL_0020
  }  // end .try
  catch [mscorlib]System.Exception 
  {
    IL_0010:  pop
    IL_0011:  nop
    IL_0012:  ldstr      "Err"
    IL_0017:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_001c:  nop
    IL_001d:  nop
    IL_001e:  leave.s    IL_0020
  }  // end handler
  IL_0020:  nop
  IL_0021:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

If you can analyze that your current code (say it is at `"OK"`) is inside that block you could extract the `try ... catch` block. This of course doesn't take calling other methods in account.

It also sounds like a ridiculous solution to the problem you have, so before you throw yourself in something you don't want, think over if you really want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You asked the wrong question, my friend!

Most frameworks allow for uncaught exceptions to be handled by a particular method. WPF, C# webforms, asp, all of these have an "unhandled exception handling" routine you can hook in to in the application level.

For instance, normal C# forms apps use:

```
    Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(MyCommonExceptionHandlingMethod)

private static void MyCommonExceptionHandlingMethod(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs t)
{
    //Exception handling...
}
```

So you would just need to declare your exceptionmanager class, then have the class hooked into the exception handling, for instance:

```
    Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(TellMyClass)

private static void TellMyClass(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs t)
{
     ExceptionManager.HandleException(sender, t);
}
```

However, the pattern I've used is:

```
public static class UnhandledExceptionManager {
    Logger _logger;
    public static void RegisterToHandleFormsException(){
        _logger = new Logger();
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
        Application.ThreadException += OnThreadException;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
    }

    public static void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e){
        HandleException((Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
    }
    private static void HandleException(Exception exception, [CallerMemberName] string methodName = "")
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.Error(methodName, exception);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("({0}) {1}", methodName, e);
            }
        }
}
```

Which is used in the Program.cs:

```
public static void Main(){
  UnhandledExceptionManager.RegisterToHandleFormsException();
  //etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CLR exceptions *on Windows* are just another SEH. Read the classic: [A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32™ Structured Exception Handling](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx). Obviously it is possible to detect that your code runs during a SEH handler, since [`ExceptionNestedException`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/10/01/51524.aspx) must be detected. The [TEB](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S2CE.aspx) contains everything needed, provided you you are the OS or a debugger and know how to interpret it.

For you, I would strongly recommend to back off and go down the documented path. If needed, wrap your logging in try/catch blocks to avoid leaking exceptions from code that is required to not throw. Make sure you handle [`ThreadAbortException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception(v=vs.110).aspx) properly since is so *special*. Hook into [`Application.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception(v=vs.95).aspx), [`Application.ThreadException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx), as appropriate, with proper logging and error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answers, you can't.  You can fake it by passing a parameter to the method, but that seems to be a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it the easy way:

```
void SomeFunction(bool isCalledFromCatch)
{
    // how do I detect whether I am being called from within a catch block?
}

try
{
}
catch(...)
{
    SomeFunction(true);
}
```