# I want to make a method that throws new exception which is then caught where the method is called from

Tags: c#, if-statement, exception, console, try-catch

I have this method which i want to throw a new exception from

```
public void AddProduct(Product product1, Category category)
        {

        var addPToCat = new Program();
        var productExistInCategory = ProductDictionary.Any(x => x.Key == product1.ArticleNumber);

        if (!productExistInCategory)
        {
            ProductDictionary.Add(product1.ArticleNumber, category.Name );
        }
    }
```

The `AddProduct()` method is called from this method which i want to catch the exception:

```
 public void AddProductToCategory()
    {
        if (productExist)
        {
            if (categoryExist != null)
            {
                categoryExist.AddProduct(product, categoryExist);
                try
                {
                    if (productExistInCategoryInCategory)
                        categoryExist.ProductDictionary.Add(product.ArticleNumber, categoryName);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Produkten finns redan");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    throw new ArgumentException("Produkten finns redan");
                }
            }
    }
```

Am i doing it right or is there something wrong?

Comment: There's no exception thrown in that first method so... that's a problem. Also, if you want to catch an exception thrown by `AddProduct` then the call to `AddProduct` would have to be inside the `try` block. Basically, it appears that you understanding of exceptions is severely deficient so I suggest that you do some more reading on the subject.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73628685/10024425 and https://berserkerdotnet.github.io/blog/rethrow-exception-correctly-in-dotnet/

Comment: Exceptions are a feeble way to pass along information such as success and failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you want to call the `AddProduct` method inside the `try` from `AddProductToCategory` method like this

```
 public void AddProductToCategory()
{
    try
        {
          categoryExist.AddProduct(product, categoryExist);
        }
}
```

And then in the `AddProduct` method you have to throw the exception like the exemple givng below:

```
public void AddProduct(Product product1, Category category)
       {
              if (productExistInCategory)
            {
               throw new ArgumentException();
            }
       }
```

And then go back to `AddProductToCategory` method and catch the exception like that:

> NOTE: Dont change the code in `try`

```
 public void AddProductToCategory()
    {

        if (productExist)
        {
            if (categoryExist != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    categoryExist.AddProduct(product, categoryExist);
                }
                catch (ArgumentException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Produkten finns redan");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

And there you go.

**What we did was to `try` the `AddProduct` method untill we find or `catch` the exception we threw before, and thats it**