# Custom exception- Try catch - in c#

Tags: c#, .net, exception

it is allowed to use custom exception, where the exception can be thrown like below.

```
  try
{
    int foo = int.Parse(token);
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
    //Assuming you added this constructor
    throw new ParserException(
      $"Failed to read {token} as number.", 
      FileName, 
      LineNumber, 
      ex);
}
```

But in a normal try catch block, it says , throwing exceptions will clear the stacktrace.

```
 try
      {
        ForthCall();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw ex;
      }
```

So in custom exception,how it managed to use throw exception, without clear the stacktrace?

Comment: You pass the original exception from try block(FormatException) as inner exception in constructor of ParserException, so you can can get the original stack trace through the InnerException member

Comment: How do you say it as inner exception?

Comment: According to your code from the link you mentioned. However this link does't provide complete implementation of contructor you used. Just modify this one ParserException(string msg, Exception inner) : base(msg, inner) {
}. so while catching your custom excexption you can get the original stack as YourCustomExceptionObject.InnerException.StackTrace

Comment: just say `throw` not `throw ex`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways this can be done.

As mentioned in this link [In C#, how can I rethrow InnerException without losing stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383/in-c-how-can-i-rethrow-innerexception-without-losing-stack-trace), you can use the [ExceptionDispatchInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo.aspx)
with code similar to

```
try
{
    task.Wait();
}
catch(AggregateException ex)
{
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
}
```

Another way is to have your handler return a boolean, whether the exception was handled or not, so you can use this in your catch clause:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
  if (!HandleException(ex)) {
    throw;
  }
}
```

where `HandleException` is your custom Exception handler. Gotten from this link: [How to throw exception without resetting stack trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730300/how-to-throw-exception-without-resetting-stack-trace)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `throw` with an exception object, it fills in the stack trace at that point. (Compare to Java, which populates stack traces when an exception is constructed.)

If you use `throw` without an exception object, which you can only do in a `catch` clause, the caught exception object is re-throw without alteration.