# throw; throw ex; optimal

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET - Throwing Exceptions best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623/net-throwing-exceptions-best-practices)

Hi,

I have seen people re-throwing exceptions as given below. which one is optimal? Why one mechanism is optimal than the other one.

```
try
{
   // do something
}
catch (exception ex)
{
   // do something
   throw ex;
}
```

---

```
try
{
    // do something
}
catch (exception ex)
{
   // do something
   throw;
}
```

Comment: Same as [
.NET - Throwing Exceptions best practices
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623/net-throwing-exceptions-best-practices).

Answer (score 0):

well, I don't know about others, but sometimes we do the second method to log the error and then catch it somewhere else.