# Throw exception from Called function to the Caller Function's Catch Block

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch-finally

```
internal static string ReadCSVFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        ...
    }
}


//Reading File Contents

public void ReadFile()
{
    try
    {
        ...
        ReadCSVFile(filePath);
        ...
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        ...
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here in the above code sample, I have two functions `ReadFile` and `ReadCSVFile`.
In the `ReadCSVFile`, I get an exception of type FileNotFoundException, which gets caught in the catch(FileNotFoundException) block. But when I throw this exception to be caught in the catch(FileNotFoundException) of the `ReadFile` Function, it gets caught in the catch(Exception) block rather than catch(FileNotFoundException). Moreover,  while debugging, the value of the ex says as Object Not Initialized. How can I throw the exception from the called function to the caller function's catch block without losing the inner exception or atleast the exception message?

Comment: as you use the same exception local object, are you sure the inner exception is of type `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET - Throwing Exceptions best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623/net-throwing-exceptions-best-practices)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but a question lacking informatio to show why it is no duplicate :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to use `throw;` instead of `throw ex;`:

```
internal static string ReadCSVFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Besides that, if you do nothing in your catch block but rethrowing, you don't need the catch block at all:

```
internal static string ReadCSVFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
    finally
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Implement the catch block only:

1. when you want to handle the exception.
2. when you want to add additional information to the exception by throwing a new exception with the caught one as inner exception:

   `catch(Exception exc) { throw new MessageException("Message", exc); }`

You do not have to implement a catch block in every method where an exception can bubble through.

Comment: I tried using only throw but the result remained the same. Moreover, I am actually attaching a custom message to the exception and then throwing it.

Comment: Then you have to throw a new exception with the custom message and the caught exception as inner exception: catch(Exception exc) { throw new MessageException("Message", exc); }

Comment: The answer sounds legit, but for some reason it doesn't work- this should be simpler than initializing a new exception object at every caller function.

Comment: @vivekagarwal277 You only need to create a new outer exception when you want to add information to the inner exception.

Comment: @PVitt I don't intend to create an outer exception- I want this exception caught in the correct catch block, i.e. the catch block meant for that particular exception- not the parent class 'Exception'. Like I said- the answer looks right- but for some reason- the exception is always caught in the catch(Exception) block- specially when the caller is in another class.

Answer (score 2):

Just use throw in the called function. Dont overload catch blocks with multiple exception types. Let the caller take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace

```
throw ex;
```

by

```
throw;
```

Comment: I tried, but no help. I still get ObjectNotInitialized in the Caller's  catch block for Exception object.

Comment: This might be an other exception?

Answer (score 1):

In the called function just use throw like this

```
 try
 {
   //you code
 }
 catch
 {
     throw;
}
```

Now, if the exception arise here then this will be caught by the caller function .

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine here, Check here http://ideone.com/jOlYQ

Comment: Is there any difference if the code snippet belongs to a web service rather than a simple console code???

Comment: There should not be. A webservice is again a serivice which is hosted in some container and that could be another console app though it doesnth have an visually console represented to user. So its basically C# and nope.