# Repeating a function in C# until it no longer throws an exception

Tags: c#, exception

I've got a class that calls a SOAP interface, and gets an array of data back.  However, if this request times out, it throws an exception.  This is good.  However, I want my program to attempt to make this call again.  If it times out, I'd like it to keep making this call until it succeeds.  How can I accomplish this?

For example:

```
try
{
   salesOrdersArray = MagServ.salesOrderList(sessID, filter);
}
catch
{
   ?? What Goes Here to FORCE the above line of code to rerun until it succeeds.
}
```

Comment: Increase the timeout so it doesn't throw the exception?

Comment: You could simply call the method again from the catch block, *BUT* - what happens if the service is down for an extended period of time?  Do you want the method to run recursively for 24 hours? I would recommend limiting it to a set number of retries.

Comment: Out of all of these answers, not one person tells you to catch a more specific exception. What if your try block contains objects in an invalid state to get the `salesOrderList`? Retrying will never succeed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to loop forever:

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        salesOrdersArray = MagServ.salesOrderList(sessID, filter);
        break; // Exit the loop. Could return from the method, depending
               // on what it does...
    }
    catch
    {
        // Log, I suspect...
    }
}
```

Note that you should almost certainly *not* actually loop forever. You should almost certainly have a maximum number of attempts, and probably only catch *specific* exceptions. Catching *all* exceptions *forever* could be appalling... imagine if `salesOrderList` (unconventional method name, btw) throws `ArgumentNullException` because you've got a bug and `filter` is null... do you *really* want to tie up 100% of your CPU forever?

Comment: Couldn't that (potentially) tie up system resources and/or make the calling app unresponsive?  Doesn't sound like the best solution to me...

Comment: @Tim: I was adding the paragraph below - basically the code answers the question directly, but the paragraph explains that it's probably not a good idea :)

Comment: +1 for specific exceptions, I was typing my comment on the question during your edit.

Comment: I know, I do catch specific exceptions, SOAP errors, etc.  Forgot the joys of break, thanks.

Comment: @psyklopz: You specify the exception type in the catch block: `catch (SoapException)` etc. You can specify multiple different exception types in multiple catch blocks.

Comment: When I do this sort of thing, I put in a `Sleep` of appropriate duration so that it doesn't use 100% of the CPU waiting for some service to come back online. I might even include a limited exponential backoff (like TCP) so that it recovers quickly from minor network glitches but tries once every few minutes if the service is down for an extended period.

Comment: You can also get current time before and then wait till the diff b/w then and now is > 5 sec and then break out (or however long you want)

Answer (score 5):

You must place the try/catch block inside a loop construct. If you wish not to consume 100% of your processor place a Thread.Sleep in the catch block, so everytime an exception occurs, it will wait some time, freeing the processor to do other things.

```
// iterate 100 times... not forever!
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    try {
        // do your work here;

        break; // break the loop if everything is fine
    } catch {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

You could also specify exception type, so that only the timeout exception is handled, and other kinds of exceptions pass-through.

```
// iterate 100 times... not forever!
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    try {
        // do your work here;

        break; // break the loop if everything is fine
    } catch (TimeOutException) {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Note that, TimeOutException should be replaced by the real name of the exception... I don't know if that is the real name.

Also adjust the sleep time, given in millisecs and the amount of repeats, in the case I presented, 100 repeats of 1000ms yields a maximum wait of 1 minute and 40 seconds, plus the operation time itself.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't change the timeout, the below should work.  salesOrdersArray should be initialized to `null`.

```
while(salesOrdersArray == null)
{
    try
    {
       salesOrdersArray = MagServ.salesOrderList(sessID, filter);
    }
    catch
    {
       // Log failure
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: I like this a bit better than Jon's answer.  I think it makes the end condition of the loop more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

It its not gernally a good idead to use exceptions as control flow, but this will do what you requested.

```
bool Caught = true;
while (Caught)
try
{
    salesOrdersArray = MagServ.salesOrderList(sessID, filter);
    Caught = false;
}
catch
{
    Caught = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will use a **transactional** queue (MSMQ) to store the service call. A loop will dequeue messages and call the service in a TransactionScope, if the call fails the message appear to be still in the queue. An ov erall timeout can be specified by adding a time to expire in the message.  This solution is good if you really want a reliable solution since I guessed that calling that operation is critical.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool repeat = true;
while (repeat)
{
    try
    {
       salesOrdersArray = MagServ.salesOrderList(sessID, filter);
       repeat = false;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bool failed = false;
do {
 try
 {
  salesOrdersArray = MagServ.salesOrderList(sessID, filter);
 }
 catch
 {
  failed = true;
 }
} while(failed);
```

The behavior you are after might cause an endless loop if this never succeeds though...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var failed = true;
while (failed)
{
  try 
  {
    salesOrdersArray = MagServ.salesOrderList(sessID, filter); 
    failed = false;
  }
  catch
  {
  }
}
```

Edit: Wow! Great minds think alike! :)

Answer (score 0):

Although I would NOT recommend you to do this for an infinite number of times, you could make a separate function out of that one sentence:

```
void GoConnect()
{
    try
    {
        salesOrdersArray = MagServ.salesOrderList(sessID, filter);
    }
    catch
    {
        GoConnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(salesOrdersArray == null){

  try
  {
    salesOrdersArray = MagServ.salesOrderList(sessID, filter);
  }
  catch(salesOrderException e)
  {
     log(e.message);
  }
}
```

This will run forever, and is using exceptions as a loop which is slow.  Is there a way you can modify your function that it returns null, instead of throwing an exception? If you're expecting that this call will fail regularly, don't use a try/catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I follow this pattern in order to solve this problem:

```
    public void Send(String data, Int32 attemptNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            yourCodeHere(data);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (attemptNumber > 0)
                Send(data, --attemptNumber);
            else
                throw new AttemptNumberExceededException("Attempt number exceeded!", ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log pourpose code goes here!
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Trying forever seems not to be a good idea as you may end up having an infinite process. If you think you need many attempts to achieve your goal just set huge number here.

I personally think its wise to wait some milliseconds, or seconds after eac attempt  *Thread.Sleep(1000);* before callig *Send(data);* --- you could for example, use the attempNumber variable to increse or decrease this waiting time if you think its wise for your scenario.

Comment: why shouldnt I? My point is the same as Jon Skeet, below the code he wrote

Comment: Don't `throw ex;` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178456/what-is-the-proper-way-to-re-throw-an-exception-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623/net-throwing-exceptions-best-practices

Comment: thanks @asawyer didn't know about that so I edited my answer! is that ok now?

Comment: Two things: 1- You almost never want to catch the base exception class, and if you do, it's pretty much only for logging purposes, and then `throw`ing again. 2 - Never throw the base `Exception` class. You are forcing consuming code into the bad practice of catching `Exception`. Use a more appropriate subclass, or create your own.

Comment: it makes real sense...! never thought this way... sorry for boring you, what about now?

Comment: Just take a little time to read up on best practices, and you'll be in business in no time. Heres a couple good links: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/exceptionbestpractices.aspx