# Get SQL Server CE path form multiple projects

Tags: c#, web-config, sql-server-ce, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

To learn ServiceStack, I'm developing an API based in Northwind database (a SQL Server CE sdf file). My solution has 3 projects:

- Northwind.Data. *Database and POCO classes*
- Northwind.ServiceModel. *DTO classes*
- Northwind.ServiceInstance. *Service classes*

What's the best way to access data? Currently the database is in Northwind.Data /App_Data folder. Can I access database path from Web.config and read it in AppHost class to create IDbConnection factory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**What's the best way to access data?**
I don't think OrmLite has support for SQL Server CE but there is [this](https://gist.github.com/slyngelstat/1843193). Best way might be to just use [SqlCeConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) within your Services.

**Can I access database path from Web.config and read it in AppHost class to create IDbConnection factory?**
You should be able to add the connection string to the Web.config file.

```
<add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=C:\Northwind.sdf" />
```

If I'm correct about OrmLite not supporting SQL CE and you want  `IDbConnectionFactory` like syntax in your Services you could look into using [DBProviderFactories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wda6c36e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The simplest (not the best) thing I can think of would be doing something like below.

**Create a 'bare bones' factory for SqlCEConnection. This assumes you have the connection string in your Web.config file**

```
public class SqlCeFactory
{
    public SqlCeConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        var conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ToString());
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            return conn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

**Register it the SqlLCeFactory in your AppHost**

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    container.Register<SqlCeFactory>(new SqlCeFactory());
}
```

**Inject it into your Service(s)**

```
public class SourceService : ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service
{
    public SqlCeFactory DbFactory { get; set; }

    public object Get(SomeRequest request)
    {
        using (var con = DbFactory.OpenConnection())
        {
            //use SqlCeConnection()
        }

        //more code
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove this: `catch (Exception ex) throw ex;` That will discard the stack trace. See [Exceptions Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623/).

Comment: Thanks for replies.

@paaschpa currently my sdf file is in Northwind.Data/App_Data folder (in the project Northwind.Data). What I want to do is access  (ConnectionString in web.config) from Northwind.ServiceInstance project (AppHost.Configure method).