# Best practice to handle and throw FaultException

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I am in situation where I need to find the best possible approach to do this,

```
try
{
  // Service call.
}
 catch (FaultException exception)
      {
        service.Abort();
        throw new FaultException(Resources.UnexpectedErrorOccurredAtServer, exception);
      }
```

Or

```
catch (FaultException exception)
      {
        service.Abort();
        throw new Exception(Resources.UnexpectedErrorOccurredAtServer, exception);
      }
```

// Caller.

```
Main()
{
try
{
 serviceCaller()
}
catch(FaultException ex)
{
  // Should we have this catch???
}
catch( Exception ex)
{
  // Handle unexpected errors.
}
```

what will be the best approach to throw the expected exception to caller. 
If we throw FaultException caller main method should Handle it explicitly or general exception will work.

Answer (score 4):

The best approach would be

```
try
{
  // ...
}
catch (FaultException ex)
{
    service.Abort();
    throw;
}
```

This preserves the stack trace, which your proposed methods do not. See [Throwing Exceptions best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623/throwing-exceptions-best-practices).

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested to check [WCF error handling and some best practices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/01/25/wcf-error-handling-and-some-best-practices.aspx)

The best approach would be like this:-

```
try
{
  proxy.SomeOperation();
}
catch (FaultException<MyFaultInfo> ex)
{
  // only if a fault contract was specified
}
catch (FaultException ex)
{
  // any other faults
}
catch (CommunicationException ex)
{
  // any communication errors?
}
```