# Throwing specific exception when using Polly

Tags: c#, rest, polly

I am using [polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) policy for retry attempts in the following way:

```
results = await Policy
                .Handle<WebException>()
                .WaitAndRetryAsync
                (
                    retryCount: 5,
                    sleepDurationProvider: retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt))
                )
                .ExecuteAsync(async () => await task.Invoke());
```

I am using the [AsyncErrorHandler](https://github.com/Fody/AsyncErrorHandler) to handle all the web exceptions:

```
public static class AsyncErrorHandler
{
    public static void HandleException(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

However some of the expections I would like to throw up to the GUI. 
With this code in place how can I prevent handling of a specific exception and instead throw it to the GUI?

[UPDATE] If I throw a specific exception inside the HandleException function I receive an Unhandled Error Message dialog in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement it differently to only throw errors on the ones you want displayed to a user, then catch those you want to throw and do what you want with their contents (either show to user or not).

```
try
{
      results = await Policy
            .Handle<WebException>()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync
            (
                retryCount: 5,
                sleepDurationProvider: retryAttempt =>  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt))
            )
            .ExecuteAsync(async () => await task.Invoke());
}

catch (ExceptionToThrowToUser ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}


public static class AsyncErrorHandler
{
    public static void HandleException(Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is ExceptionToThrowToUser)
        {
           throw;               
        }
        else
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Editted for update.

For help handling errors: [Best practices for catching and re-throwing .NET exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623/throwing-exceptions-best-practices?rq=1)

Comment: The code you posted, though, doesn't use the AsyncErrorHandler that's cited in the question.

Comment: The HandleException is always called when I receive an exception. If I throw the error inside the AsyncErrorHandler class a dialog pops up in Visual Studio showing the error instead of populating the exception up to the GUI.

Comment: How are you throwing?  Are you just showing the message or literally throw ex;?  That's why I personally just throw the message in a MessageBox for the user to see if I want them to.

Comment: Updated answer.  Yeah, you still have to handle the error in your code after it is thrown!

Comment: Yes, I am just throwing the ex because I want to handle it specially in the GUI code, clearing some variables.

Comment: Well, this should throw it and catch it where you have the catch statement.

Comment: The problem seems to be when I try to throw it within the AsyncErrorHandler class which catches all the exceptions. It doesn´t propogate to the GUI from there resulting in a Unhandled Error Message. I will check with the author.

Comment: Yeah!  You have to handle it there, glad it helped!