# ASP.NET before throw UserFriendlyException insert a log to db

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, savechanges

I want to insert a log into the database and throw a UserFriendlyException but it doesn't work as I expect

```
            if (isTodayOpen) //today open but time not valid
            {
                var logMessage = string.Format("The door cannot be unlocked. Your booking is not yet in effect. It is valid from {0} to {1}. Please try again later.", application.Rules.TimeFrom.ToString(), application.Rules.TimeTo.ToString());

                 var openDoorLogDetails = new OpenDoorLog();
                    openDoorLogDetails.ApplicantId = application.User.Id;
                    openDoorLogDetails.OpenDoorTime = DateTime.Now;
                    openDoorLogDetails.isOpenSuccessful = false;
                    openDoorLogDetails.LogMessage = logMessage;
                    await _openDoorLogRepository.InsertAsync(openDoorLogDetails);
                    await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

                    throw new UserFriendlyException(logMessage);
            }
```

what I get on Swagger

{
"result": null,
"targetUrl": null,
"success": false,
"error": {
"code": 0,
"message": "The door cannot be unlocked. Your booking is not yet in effect. It is valid from 09:00:00 to 10:00:00. Please try again later.",
"details": null,
"validationErrors": null
},
"unAuthorizedRequest": false,
"__abp": true
}

even though I use the CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges(); it only throws the exception but the log doesn't insert into a database. My expected result is the **log can be** **inserted into the database** and can **throw UserFriendlyException to the user**.

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: Does `_openDoorLogRepository` and `CurrentUnitOfWork` use same context?

Comment: I didn't declare a context for CurrentUnitOfWork

Comment: what are you expecting to happen? can you provide a fully reproducible example?

Comment: I am currently working on an API to check if an applicant can open a door. If all the conditions (time and date) are met, it will return true and save the record of the door being opened in the database. If the door cannot be opened, it needs to throw an exception. Of course, I also need to save the record of the failed door opening attempt in the database. The reason I throw a UserFriendlyException when the door cannot be opened, instead of returning false, is to meet the requirement of my colleague. The code I provided is what should be executed when the time hasn't arrived yet.

Comment: what is wrong with code?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to work with async operation in repository you need to write save changes as below:

```
await _openDoorLogRepository.InsertAsync(openDoorLogDetails);
await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Sry I forgot to put it back after I modified my code, but it still can't solve my problem

Comment: you need to explain what to expect.

Comment: I expected the open door log can be inserted into the database and also throw a UserFriendlyException to the user.

Comment: @ChuaHongYong may be your log is not save in database because when any error throw you have rollback the transaction scope using `UnitOfWork` so to solve the issue. I think now you able to understand the way. you need to omit rollback if error type is specified.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should avoid the use of exception as way to handle the logic of your application. That is easier as first but you will have, at some point ,performance issues. (see those insightfull [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336192/is-it-a-good-practice-to-throw-exceptions) and [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29433/how-to-write-a-good-exception-message)).

Best would be to return from the function the result (`return` keyword or the `ref` keyword or the `out` keyword ?)

Anyway for me the error message seems fine. If you want the minimum update of your code, you can add to your UserFriendlyException field like Context, Problem, Solution. (See [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031530/custom-exception-with-properties))

```cs
[Serializable()]
public class UserFriendlyException : Exception, ISerializable {
  public string Context;
  // message of exeption used as Problem section
  public string Solution;
  public UserFriendlyException () : base() { }
  public UserFriendlyException (string message) : base(message) { }
  public UserFriendlyException (string message, System.Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
  public UserFriendlyException (SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
  public UserFriendlyException (string message, string context, string solution) : base(message) {
      this.Context= context;
      this.Solution= solution;
    }
  }

// ...
// In your code 
// ...
if (isTodayOpen) //today open but time not valid
            {
                var logMessage = "The door cannot be unlocked. Your booking is not yet in effect.";

                 var openDoorLogDetails = new OpenDoorLog();
                    openDoorLogDetails.ApplicantId = application.User.Id;
                    openDoorLogDetails.OpenDoorTime = DateTime.Now;
                    openDoorLogDetails.isOpenSuccessful = false;
                    openDoorLogDetails.LogMessage = logMessage;
                    await _openDoorLogRepository.InsertAsync(openDoorLogDetails);
                    await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

                    throw new UserFriendlyException(
                         message: logMessage,
                         context : "Application booking door is open but time is invalid",
                         solution : $"It is valid from {application.Rules.TimeFrom.ToString()} to {application.Rules.TimeTo.ToString()}. Please try again later." 
                    );
            }
// ...
```

You will have a reply like that :

```json
{
    "__abp": true,
    "error": {
        "code": 0,
        "details": null,
        "message": "The door cannot be unlocked. Your booking is not yet in effect.",
        "context":"Application booking door is open but time is invalid",
        "solution":"It is valid from 09:00:00 to 10:00:00. Please try again later.",
        "validationErrors": null
    },
    "result": null,
    "success": false,
    "targetUrl": null,
    "unAuthorizedRequest": false
}
```

If you still want the message error only, you can make a try catch at very hight level of your app and `catch(UserFriendlyException ex) { return ex.Message}`. But you should define a proper error message template regarding how this data will be consumed (directl by the user ? via front end ?).

Take care