# How to throw an exception

Tags: c#, exception, c#-4.0, try-catch, throw

What are the best practices for choosing between `throw;` and `throw ex;`? Is there any at all? Regarding, for example, this simple snippet:

```
try{
    // some code
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // some catcher code
    // throw; ?
    // or
    // throw ex; ?
    // how to decide which one?
}
```

I know the difference between the two above. How can I decide to use one of them? Is there a best practice to making a better choice?

Comment: Use `throw`, this keeps the original stacktrace. But why would you catch a general exception at all? Seems to me you cannot handle it, so why catch it?

Comment: @Maarten it would happen sometimes. retrying of some operations for example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between "throw" and "throw ex"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex)

Comment: @Sinatr see the update please. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's very simple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/730250/1997232).

Do you want to keep the stack trace to see exactly where the exception occurs? Then use `throw`. This will be like if you don't use `catch` at all.

Do you only care about the **current method's** debug information? Then use `throw ex`.

To demonstrate:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Test();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}

static void Test()
{
    try
    {
        // long lambda chain
        new Action(() => new Action(() => new Action(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException(); })())())();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //throw;
        //throw ex;
    }
}
```

`throw` will keep the stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
    at ConsoleApplication.Program.<>c.<Test>b__1_2() in ConsoleApplication\Program.cs:line 22
    at ConsoleApplication.Program.<>c.<Test>b__1_1() in ConsoleApplication\Program.cs:line 22
    at ConsoleApplication.Program.<>c.<Test>b__1_0() in ConsoleApplication\Program.cs:line 22
    at ConsoleApplication.Program.Test() in ConsoleApplication\Program.cs:line 26
    at ConsoleApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in ConsoleApplication\Program.cs:line 13
```

`throw ex` will reset stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
    at ConsoleApplication.Program.Test() in ConsoleApplication\Program.cs:line 27
    at ConsoleApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in ConsoleApplication\Program.cs:line 13
```

As for *best practices* - the choice [is usually `throw`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22623/1997232). As a developer, you want to get as much information as you can. `throw ex` is a counterpart - some information is hidden, but maybe you want to hide it, who knows?

Answer (score 8):

You should either use `throw;` to rethrow the original exception (with the original stack trace) or use `throw new MyException(..., ex);` to throw your own exception that may provide additional information *and* set the inner exception to `ex`.

If you don't have any additional information, just use `throw;`.

If you only catch the exception to do cleanup, then use `try {...} finally {...}` instead.